# Dealing with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" error

Tags: exception, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, java-6, permgen

Recently I ran into this error in my web application:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

It's a typical Hibernate/JPA + IceFaces/JSF application running on Tomcat 6 and JDK 1.6.
Apparently this can occur after redeploying an application a few times.

What causes it and what can be done to avoid it?
How do I fix the problem?

Comment: I have fought this for hours, but I have no good news. See my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996088/java-class-permgen-memory-leak-web-applications-generic-solution You may still have a memory leak, e.g. classes are not garbage collected because your WebAppClassLoader is not garbage collected (it has an external reference that is not cleared). increasing the PermGen will only delay the OutOfMemoryError, and allowing class garbage collection is a precondition, but will not garbage collect classes if their class loader still has references to it.

Comment: I got this error at adding [display taglib](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/displaytag/displaytag/1.2). Removing so also solved the error. Why so?

Comment: And how did you run into it?

Comment: use JDK 1.8 :þ welcome to the MetaSpace

Comment: If using Windows, follow these instructions instead of trying to set the flags manually in the config files.  This properly sets the values in the registry to be called by Tomcat during runtime.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104340/increase-windows-installer-based-tomcat-permgen-space

Answer (score 572, accepted):

The solution was to add these flags to JVM command line when Tomcat is started:

```
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
```

You can do that by shutting down the tomcat service, then going into the Tomcat/bin directory and running tomcat6w.exe. Under the "Java" tab, add the arguments to the "Java Options" box. Click "OK" and then restart the service.

If you get an error *the specified service does not exist as an installed service* you should run:

```
tomcat6w //ES//servicename
```

where ***servicename*** is the name of the server as viewed in services.msc

Source: orx's comment on [Eric's Agile Answers](https://web.archive.org/web/20160124133922/http://www.jroller.com/agileanswers/entry/preventing_java_s_java_lang).

Comment: The article below suggests -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC and -XX:MaxPermSize=128m as well.

http://my.opera.com/karmazilla/blog/2007/03/13/good-riddance-permgen-outofmemoryerror

Comment: -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled  This option brings down performance. It makes each request take three times more time than usual on our systems. Use with care.

Comment: worked for me - thanks - I am doing this on Ubuntu 10.10 with Tomcat6 - I created a new file: /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/setenv.sh and added the following line to that: JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled" - Restarted tomcat using: sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start

Comment: On tomcat 6.0.29 startup, from my catalina.out logfile: "Please use CMSClassUnloadingEnabled in place of CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled in the future"

Comment: On a tomcat 5.5 on Ubuntu I've changed /etc/default/tomcat5.5 with the following JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms128M -Xmx512M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"

Comment: I'm not able to open up tomcat6w.exe :( It says "The specified service does not exist as an installed service. Unable to open the service 'tomcat6' " . Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: First of all it would be great to explain what these flags really do. Just saying: "do that and enjoy" is not enough IMHO.

Comment: And second, if your application really leaks class loader, meaning that it leaves somewhere some object or class loaded by application's class loader even after undeployment, then these flags will not help. I have written blog post about this and other suggestions in this topic: http://plumbr.eu/blog/busting-permgen-myths

Comment: -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled and -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled are unusable in java 1.7, see [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#BehavioralOptions)

Comment: @lolotron, With Java `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)`... running `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version`... the returned list of flags includes `CMSClassUnloadingEnabled`.

Comment: @lolotron vulgarly trying to set it on tomcat 7 on "Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)", it works fine (no more OutOfMemory errors).

Comment: To know more about the flags - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334911/what-does-jvm-flag-cmsclassunloadingenabled-actually-do

Comment: A bit dated, like this thread, but here's documentation from Oracle:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html#0.0.0.%20When%20to%20Use%20the%20Concurrent%20Low%20Pause%20Collector|outline

Comment: I can do this on tomcat 7: add this line to setenv.sh [JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled" ] ? will this work?

Comment: what worked for me on windows: created file `${tomcat-folder}\bin\setenv.bat` containing one line: `set JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

Comment: The correct solution is to address the memory leak problems and resolve them. If you registered JDBC Drivers, unregister them. You can use a javax.servlet.ServletContextListener. I have posted a solution below with a sample code to unregister drivers / threads / etc.

Comment: What if I'm running a WebLogic?

Comment: Note that CMSClassUnloadingEnabled is enabled by default

Comment: Any reason why these aren't enabled by default?

Answer (score 252):

You better try **`-XX:MaxPermSize=128M`** rather than `-XX:MaxPermGen=128M`.

I can not tell the precise use of this memory pool, but it have to do with the number of classes loaded into the JVM. (Thus enabling class unloading for tomcat can resolve the problem.) If your applications generates and compiles classes on the run it is more likely to need a memory pool bigger than the default.

Comment: Actually, this will only postpone OOMError. See answer below started by anon with two links to frankkieviet blog.

Comment: These options are explained here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#PerformanceTuning

Answer (score 154):

App server PermGen errors that happen after multiple deployments are most likely caused by references held by the container into your old apps' classloaders. For example, using a custom log level class will cause references to be held by the app server's classloader. You can detect these inter-classloader leaks by using modern (JDK6+) JVM analysis tools such as jmap and jhat to look at which classes continue to be held in your app, and redesigning or eliminating their use. Usual suspects are databases, loggers, and other base-framework-level libraries.

See [Classloader leaks: the dreaded "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" exception](http://frankkieviet.blogspot.ca/2006/10/classloader-leaks-dreaded-permgen-space.html), and especially its [followup post](http://frankkieviet.blogspot.ca/2006/10/how-to-fix-dreaded-permgen-space.html).

Comment: This is only true solution to the problem, ableit in some cases too hard to implement.

Comment: Another very good source is http://people.apache.org/~markt/presentations/2010-11-04-Memory-Leaks-60mins.pdf (from Tomcat release manager!!).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 69):

Common mistakes people make is thinking that heap space and permgen space are same, which is not at all true.  You could have lot of space remaining in the heap but still can run out of memory in permgen.

Common causes of OutofMemory in PermGen is ClassLoader. Whenever a class is loaded into JVM, all its meta data, along with Classloader, is kept on PermGen area and they will be garbage collected when the Classloader which loaded them is ready for garbage collection. In Case Classloader has a memory leak than all classes loaded by it will remain in memory and cause permGen outofmemory once you repeat it a couple of times.  The classical example is [Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:PermGen Space in Tomcat](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen.html).

Now there are two ways to solve this:
1. Find the cause of Memory Leak or if there is any memory leak.
2. Increase size of PermGen Space by using JVM param `-XX:MaxPermSize` and `-XX:PermSize`.

You can also check [2 Solution of Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space.html) in Java for more details.

Comment: How to pass param `-XX:MaxPermSize and -XX:PermSize`?? I can't find `catalina.bat`. My tomcat version is `5.5.26`.

Comment: How to find the memory leaks of class loader ? Do you recommend any tool ?

Comment: @amit for tool recommendations, see the community wiki answer on this question.

Comment: @Deckard going into the Tomcat/bin directory and running tomcat6w.exe. Under the "Java" tab, add the arguments to the "Java Options" box. Click "OK"

Answer (score 43):

Use the command line parameter `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m` for a Sun JVM (obviously substituting 128 for whatever size you need).

Comment: The only issue is that you're just delaying the inevitable- at some point you'll run out of headroom there too. It's a great pragmatic solution, but it doesn't solve it permanently.

Comment: same thing occurs in Eclipse and any time you have lots of dynamic class loading.  the classloaders aren't disposed of and live in the permanent generation for all eternity

Comment: I was running out of PermGen when executing a particularly large Hudson job...this fixed it for me.

Comment: @TimHowland, it can be a permanent fix if the root cause is not classloader leakage, just too many classes/static data in your web app.

Comment: got the same issue as HDave when building jenkins/hudson from source.

Answer (score 40):

Try `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m` and if it persists, try `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

Comment: and if it still persist try `XX:MaxPermSize=1024m` :)

Comment: and if it still persist try XX:MaxPermSize=2048m :)

Comment: And if it STILL persists, rethink your application!! Or try XX:MaxPermSize=4096m :)

Comment: you can also try 8192m but thats a bit of overkill

Comment: Overkill indeed --  640KB ought to be enough for anybody!

Comment: let's see... 2012 ppl say 1024, 2013 is 2048, 2014 it was 4096 and 2015 arrives at 8192. Now just spend that $100 for your 16384.

Comment: Well I had same issue, so all I did is XX:MaxPermSize=131072m :)

Answer (score 29):

I [added](https://stackoverflow.com/a/835269/432903) `-XX: MaxPermSize = 128m` (you can experiment which works best) to **VM Arguments** as I'm using eclipse ide. In most of JVM, [default PermSize](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space.html) is around **64MB** which runs out of memory if there are too many classes or huge number of Strings in the project.

For eclipse, it is also described at [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4350922/432903).

**STEP 1** : Double Click on the tomcat server at **Servers** Tab

[image]

**STEP 2** : **Open launch Conf** and add `-XX: MaxPermSize = 128m` to the end of existing **VM arguements**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your best detailed answer (Note : click "Open launch configuration" to open "edit configuration" window... but I used the following parameters: "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled"

Answer (score 23):

I've been butting my head against this problem while deploying and undeploying a complex web application too, and thought I'd add an explanation and my solution.

When I deploy an application on Apache Tomcat, a new ClassLoader is created for that app. The ClassLoader is then used to load all the application's classes, and on undeploy, everything's supposed to go away nicely. However, in reality it's not quite as simple.

One or more of the classes created during the web application's life holds a static reference which, somewhere along the line, references the ClassLoader. As the reference is originally static, no amount of garbage collecting will clean this reference up - the ClassLoader, and all the classes it's loaded, are here to stay.

And after a couple of redeploys, we encounter the OutOfMemoryError.

Now this has become a fairly serious problem. I could make sure that Tomcat is restarted after each redeploy, but that takes down the entire server, rather than just the application being redeployed, which is often not feasible.

So instead I've put together a solution in code, which works on Apache Tomcat 6.0. I've not tested on any other application servers, and must stress that **this is very likely not to work without modification on any other application server**.

I'd also like to say that personally I hate this code, and that **nobody should be using this as a "quick fix" if the existing code can be changed to use proper shutdown and cleanup methods**. The only time this should be used is if there's an external library your code is dependent on (In my case, it was a RADIUS client) that doesn't provide a means to clean up its own static references.

Anyway, on with the code. This should be called at the point where the application is undeploying - such as a servlet's destroy method or (the better approach) a ServletContextListener's contextDestroyed method.

```
//Get a list of all classes loaded by the current webapp classloader
WebappClassLoader classLoader = (WebappClassLoader) getClass().getClassLoader();
Field classLoaderClassesField = null;
Class clazz = WebappClassLoader.class;
while (classLoaderClassesField == null && clazz != null) {
    try {
        classLoaderClassesField = clazz.getDeclaredField("classes");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        //do nothing
    }
    clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
}
classLoaderClassesField.setAccessible(true);

List classes = new ArrayList((Vector)classLoaderClassesField.get(classLoader));

for (Object o : classes) {
    Class c = (Class)o;
    //Make sure you identify only the packages that are holding references to the classloader.
    //Allowing this code to clear all static references will result in all sorts
    //of horrible things (like java segfaulting).
    if (c.getName().startsWith("com.whatever")) {
        //Kill any static references within all these classes.
        for (Field f : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers())
                    && !Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers())
                    && !f.getType().isPrimitive()) {
                try {
                    f.setAccessible(true);
                    f.set(null, null);
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    //Log the exception
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

classes.clear();
```

Comment: I know it's been over 8 years since I wrote this, but somewhere between then and now I found a deeper root cause and solution.
This was that while all of the classes within the webapp are owned by the context classloader, the thread that invokes the startup and shutdown callback is owned by the parent classloader. This means that if the shutdown code initialises a thread-local variable, this will cause the parent classloader to end up holding a reference to the context classloader, preventing good cleanup.

Comment: Luckily, there's a very simple fix - move all code currently in the shutdown method into a new Thread object's run method. Then in the shutdown method, start this thread and wait for it to complete. The cleanup code will be executed identically, but any thread-local variables will remain bound to the context classloader instead of leaking.

Answer (score 20):

The `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen` space message indicates that the Permanent Generation’s area in memory is exhausted.

Any Java applications is allowed to use a limited amount of memory. The exact amount of memory your particular application can use is specified during application startup.

**Java memory is separated into different regions which can be seen in the following image:**

[image]

**Metaspace: A new memory space is born**

The JDK 8 HotSpot JVM is now using native memory for the representation of class metadata and is called Metaspace; similar to the Oracle JRockit and IBM JVM's.

**The good news is that it means no more `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen` space problems and no need for you to tune and monitor this memory space anymore using [Java_8_Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) or higher.**

Comment: `MetaSpace` also can go OutOfMemory

Answer (score 17):

Alternatively, you can switch to JRockit which handling permgen differently then sun's jvm.  It generally has better performance as well.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/jrockit/overview/index.html

Comment: While JRockit indeed has no PermGen, but this will not help in the long run. You'll get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: There is insufficient native memory` instead.

Answer (score 17):

### 1) Increasing the PermGen Memory Size

The first thing one can do is to make the size of the permanent generation heap space bigger. This cannot be done with the usual –Xms(set initial heap size) and –Xmx(set maximum heap size) JVM arguments, since as mentioned, the permanent generation heap space is entirely separate from the regular Java Heap space, 
and these arguments set the space for this regular Java heap space. However, there are similar arguments which can be used(at least with the Sun/OpenJDK jvms) to make the size of the permanent generation heap bigger:

```
 -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

Default is 64m.

### 2) Enable Sweeping

Another way to take care of that for good is to allow classes to be unloaded so your PermGen never runs out:

```
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
```

Stuff like that worked magic for me in the past. One thing though, there’s a significant performance trade off in using those, since permgen sweeps will  make like an extra 2 requests for every request you make or something along those lines. You’ll need to balance your use with the tradeoffs.

You can find the details of this error.

http://faisalbhagat.blogspot.com/2014/09/java-outofmemoryerror-permgen.html

Comment: Great post of @faisalbhagat http://faisalbhagat.blogspot.com/2014/09/java-outofmemoryerror-permgen.html

Comment: Option 2 is great, but just be warned that it should not be used in production environments. Typically best to keep it to development environments only. However PermGen is removed as of Java 8 http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/122

Answer (score 14):

I had the problem we are talking about here, my scenario is eclipse-helios + tomcat + jsf and what you were doing is making a deploy a simple application to tomcat. I was showing the same problem here, solved it as follows.

In eclipse go to **servers** tab double click on the registered server in my case tomcat 7.0, it opens my file server General registration information. On the section **"General Information"** click on the link **"Open launch configuration"** , this opens the execution of server options in the Arguments tab in VM arguments added in the end these two entries

```
-XX: MaxPermSize = 512m
-XX: PermSize = 512m
```

and ready.

Answer (score 14):

The simplest answer these days is to use Java 8.

It no longer reserves memory exclusively for PermGen space, allowing the PermGen memory to co-mingle with the regular memory pool.

Keep in mind that you will have to remove all non-standard `-XXPermGen...=...` JVM startup parameters if you don't want Java 8 to complain that they don't do anything.

Comment: Hello, this answer has already been given: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22897121/505893. Please delete your answer, for clarity. If needed you could improve the answer I mentioned. Thanks ;)

Comment: @bluish Thank you for pointing that out; however, that answer goes all sideways on talking about OutOfMemoryExceptions and leaking metadata.  It also fails to mention the very important points of removing the PermGen option.  In short, I'm not sure I would be improving the answer, but rather rewriting it.  If it was just a quick touch-up, I would feel less hesitant, but it looks like it would be much more than a quick touch-up, and I'd hate to offend the original author.  Still, this answer list is a dog's dinner of a mess, and perhaps killing my post would be best anyway.

Answer (score 8):

1. Open tomcat7w from Tomcat's bin directory or type Monitor Tomcat in start menu 
   (a tabbed window opens with various service information).
2. In the Java Options text area append this line:

   ```
   -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
   ```
3. Set Initial Memory Pool to 1024 (optional).
4. Set Maximum Memory Pool to 1024 (optional).
5. Click Ok.
6. Restart the Tomcat service.

Answer (score 7):

Perm gen space error occurs due to the use of large space rather then jvm provided space to executed the code.

The best solution for this problem in UNIX operating systems is to change some configuration on the bash file. The following steps solve the problem.

Run command `gedit .bashrc` on terminal.

Create `JAVA_OTPS` variable with following value:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

Save the bash file. Run command exec bash on the terminal. Restart the server.

I hope this approach will work on your problem. If you use a Java version lower than 8 this issue occurs sometimes. But if you use Java 8 the problem never occurs.

Answer (score 5):

Also if you are using log4j in your webapp, check this paragraph in log4j [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a3.6).

It seems that if you are using `PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch("log4j.properties")`, you cause memory leaks when you undeploy your webapp.

Answer (score 5):

Increasing Permanent Generation size or tweaking GC parameters will NOT help if you have a real memory leak. If your application or some 3rd party library it uses, leaks class loaders the only real and permanent solution is to find this leak and fix it. There are number of tools that can help you, one of the recent is [Plumbr](http://plumbr.eu), which has just released a new version with the required capabilities.

Answer (score 4):

[jrockit](/questions/tagged/jrockit) resolved this for me as well; however, I noticed that the servlet restart times were much worse, so while it was better in production, it was kind of a drag in development.

Answer (score 4):

I have a combination of Hibernate+Eclipse RCP, tried using `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m` and `-XX:PermSize=512m` and it seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 4):

Set `-XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m`. Later on you may also try increasing `MaxPermSize`. Hope it'll work. The same works for me. Setting only `MaxPermSize` didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I tried several answers and the only thing what finally did the job was this configuration for the compiler plugin in the pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <meminitial>128m</meminitial>
        <maxmem>512m</maxmem>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <!-- prevent PermGen space out of memory exception -->
        <!-- <argLine>-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</argLine> -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

hope this one helps.

Comment: "argLine" is not recognized by maven-compiler-plugin 2.4. it only supports "compilerArgument", which gives error:
    <compilerArgument>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</compilerArgument>

    [ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
    javac: invalid flag: -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
    Usage: javac <options> <source files>

Comment: If your compilation phase is running out of permgen set the <compilerArgument> on the maven-compiler-plugin. If the unit tests are running out of permgen set <argLine> in the maven-surefire-plugin

Answer (score 3):

The configuration of the memory depends on the nature of your app.

What are you doing?

What's the amount of transactions precessed?

How much data are you loading?

etc.

etc.

etc

Probably you could profile your app and start cleaning up some modules from your app.

> *Apparently this can occur after redeploying an application a few times*

Tomcat has hot deploy but it consumes memory. Try restarting your container once in a while.  Also you will need to know the amount of memory needed to run in production mode, this seems a good time for that research.

Answer (score 3):

They Say that the latest rev of Tomcat (6.0.28 or 6.0.29) handles the task of redeploying servlets **much** better.

Answer (score 3):

I run into exactly the same problem, but unfortunately none of the suggested solutions really worked for me. The problem did not happen during deployment, and I was neither doing any hot deployments.

In my case the problem occurred every time at the same point during the execution of my web-application, while connecting (via hibernate) to the database.

[This link](http://jroller.com/agileanswers/entry/preventing_java_s_java_lang) (also mentioned earlier) did provide enough insides to resolve the problem. Moving the jdbc-(mysql)-driver out of the WEB-INF and into the jre/lib/ext/ folder seems to have solved the problem. This is not the ideal solution, since upgrading to a newer JRE would require you to reinstall the driver.
Another candidate that could cause similar problems is log4j, so you might want to move that one as well

Comment: If you don't want to include the driver in jre/lib/ext, you could probably get the same results by including the driver in your container startup classpath.

java -cp /path/to/jdbc-mysql-driver.jar:/path/to/container/bootstrap.jar  container.Start

Answer (score 3):

First step in such case is to check whether the GC is allowed to unload classes from PermGen. The standard JVM is rather conservative in this regard – classes are born to live forever. So once loaded, classes stay in memory even if no code is using them anymore. This can become a problem when the application creates lots of classes dynamically and the generated classes are not needed for longer periods. In such a case, allowing the JVM to unload class definitions can be helpful. This can be achieved by adding just one configuration parameter to your startup scripts:

```
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

By default this is set to false and so to enable this you need to explicitly set the following option in Java options. If you enable CMSClassUnloadingEnabled, GC will sweep PermGen too and remove classes which are no longer used. Keep in mind that this option will work only when UseConcMarkSweepGC is also enabled using the below option. So when running ParallelGC or, God forbid, Serial GC, make sure you have set your GC to CMS by specifying:

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

Answer (score 3):

Assigning Tomcat more memory is NOT the proper solution.

The correct solution is to do a cleanup after the context is destroyed and recreated (the hot deploy). The solution is to stop the memory leaks.

If your Tomcat/Webapp Server is telling you that failed to unregister drivers (JDBC), then unregister them. This will stop the memory leaks.

You can create a ServletContextListener and configure it in your web.xml. Here is a sample ServletContextListener:

```
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread;

/**
 * 
 * @author alejandro.tkachuk / calculistik.com
 *
 */
public class AppContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AppContextListener.class);

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        logger.info("AppContextListener started");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        logger.info("AppContextListener destroyed");

        // manually unregister the JDBC drivers
        Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
        while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
            Driver driver = drivers.nextElement();
            try {
                DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
                logger.info(String.format("Unregistering jdbc driver: %s", driver));
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.info(String.format("Error unregistering driver %s", driver), e);
            }

        }

        // manually shutdown clean up threads
        try {
            AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.shutdown();
            logger.info("Shutting down AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.warn("SEVERE problem shutting down AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread: ", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }
}
```

And here you configure it in your web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        com.calculistik.mediweb.context.AppContextListener 
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 2):

"They" are wrong because I'm running 6.0.29 and have the same problem even after setting all of the options. As Tim Howland said above, these options only put off the inevitable. They allow me to redeploy 3 times before hitting the error instead of every time I redeploy.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are getting this in the eclipse IDE, even after setting the parameters 
`--launcher.XXMaxPermSize`, `-XX:MaxPermSize`, etc, still if you are getting the same error, it most likely is that the eclipse is using a buggy version of JRE which would have been installed by some third party applications and set to default. These buggy versions do not pick up the PermSize parameters and so no matter whatever you set, you still keep getting these memory errors. So, in your eclipse.ini add the following parameters:

```
-vm <path to the right JRE directory>/<name of javaw executable>
```

Also make sure you set the default JRE in the preferences in the eclipse to the correct version of java.

Answer (score 2):

The only way that worked for me was with the JRockit JVM. I have MyEclipse 8.6.

The JVM's heap stores all the objects generated by a running Java program. Java uses the `new` operator to create objects, and memory for new objects is allocated on the heap at run time. Garbage collection is the mechanism of automatically freeing up the memory contained by the objects that are no longer referenced by the program.

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar issue.
Mine is JDK 7 + Maven 3.0.2 + Struts 2.0 + Google GUICE dependency injection based project.

Whenever i tried running **`mvn clean package`** command, it was showing following error and **"BUILD FAILURE"** occured

> **org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
>   Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space**

I tried all the above useful tips and tricks but unfortunately none worked for me.
What worked for me is described step by step below :=>

1. Go to your pom.xml
2. Search for  `<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>`
3. Add a new `<configuration>` element and then `<argLine>` sub element in which pass `-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m` as shown below  =>

***`<configuration>
    <argLine>-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
  </configuration>`***

Hope it helps, happy programming :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this problem by doing a:

```
rm -rf <tomcat-dir>/work/* <tomcat-dir>/temp/*
```

Clearing out the *work* and *temp* directories makes Tomcat do a clean startup.

Answer (score 0):

If any one is struggling with the same error in netbeans, then here is how I fixed it.

**In Netbeans:**

Go to services tab --> Right on server -->Choose properties --> go to platform tab -->Inside vm options type -Xms1024m

In my case, I have given -Xms4096m

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To who is getting this same problem in IntelliJ when trying to debug JBoss Application:
I just added this `-XX: MaxPermSize = 128m` to the VM Options In Run/Debug COnfigurations. You can increase it to 256m to be more guaranteed that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Increase Tomcat Memory

`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin`

or anywhere you used tomcat. and run `tomcat9w` or any version you used.

after that follow the picture

[image]

Change 128 to 1024 and also max change it to 1024 or more as you want.