# What can be done with 'PermGen out of space' exception in Tomcat-Spring-Hibernate web application?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, tomcat5.5, permgen

We have an web application that uses Spring-Hibernate to persist registered users data in Oracle database. The application works fine in development environment, but when we copy it int live environment with much more data, it failed. Initially the application starts normally, but after few actions 'PermGen out of space' exception occured.

I've started to search in Google, Spring and Hibernate forums, but it doesn't help. There is many discussions about this error, but for each solution, there are people, that say: 'It works' and other people say 'It doesn't'.

For example, many people offer to increase `-XX:MaxPermSize` JVM parameter, other says that it doesn't works. There are posts that says that the problem in use of javassist library and others and cglib library needed to be used. Others says that the problem is in cglib.

We use Java1.5_0_09, Spring 2.5 with javaassist3.4.GA, Tomcat 5.5 as web-container and Oracle 10g as database.

Can anybody explain me what causes this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you intern()'ing a lot of strings?  Interned strings live in PermGen

Answer (score 19):

The `-XX:MaxPermSize` does work, you've just got to get the right value. The default, I believe, is 32mb for t the client-mode VM, and 64mb for the server mode VM. I suggest setting it to 256mb, if you have the memory:

```
java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

The problem occurs because Spring and Hibernate can make heavy use of runtime-generated classes, sometimes a lot of them. These generated classes all go into the PermGen memory pool, so if you use those frameworks, you often need to boost your PermGen to large amounts.

Comment: And be aware that this only delays the problem. If your application generates classes on a regular basis you'll have to restart your server every now and then.

Comment: Sadly, yes. It seems we're pretty much stuck with it.

Comment: @skaffman, does this mean any application built on top of Spring and Hibernate need to restart to prevent OOM on PermGen? I want my server up forever unless to push new code.

Comment: @CK: Very likely, yes.  100% uptime is not even possible for Google. If you want to get 99%+ uptime, you need multiple servers.

Comment: @skaffman, I am also struggling on the same issue. I am keep on getting the "PermGen" spacing issue. However I am feeling good that, I know the reason now. Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 8):

You must be aware that some versions of Tomcat have memory leaks on war redeployment. It happened to me on tomcat 6.0.x.

As suggested increase the **MaxPermSize**, this is a temporary solution for your development machine - and when you get the error, after 2-3 days, just restart the server. On production is not that simple. So this **works for development**, but this approach **doesn't work for production**, where you should have the memory leaks issues fixed.

To discover the leaks use the **jconsole** application that comes with jdk 1.6 and 1.5. You can bind to a process, and watch memory used over time.

You can also read these:

- http://frankkieviet.blogspot.com/2006/10/classloader-leaks-dreaded-permgen-space.html
- http://frankkieviet.blogspot.com/2006/10/how-to-fix-dreaded-permgen-space.html
- http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/monitoring/index.html
- http://my.opera.com/karmazilla/blog/2007/03/13/good-riddance-permgen-outofmemoryerror
- http://my.opera.com/karmazilla/blog/2007/03/15/permgen-strikes-back

Answer (score 4):

I have seen this problem with Hibernate (used without Spring). The issue there was that we were creating an instance of a [SessionFactory](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) for each user request rather than creating a single instance for the lifetime of the application.

I used the [YourKit profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/) to investigate this and discover the issue.

Answer (score 3):

As skaffman says the -XX:MaxPermSize property does work, however sometimes you can have an underlying problem that upping the limit may only defer.

Have you seen [this note](http://www.jroller.com/agileanswers/entry/preventing_java_s_java_lang)? It helped me resolve a similar problem once.
To summarise the link:

- Put JDBC driver in common/lib (as [tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) says) and not in WEB-INF/lib
- Don't put commons-logging into WEB-INF/lib since tomcat already bootstraps it

Answer (score 2):

Visual GC, now part of JDK 6, gives a very nice graphical representation of memory in real time.  You can see what's happening to eden, generational, and perm spaces.  You just won't see why.

UPDATE: It's bin/jvisualvm.exe in my JDK 1.6.0_13 distro.  Give it the PID of the process you want to monitor.

Comment: That's interesting. The PermGen pool is famously opaque, and not visible to the JVMTI debug interface. I wonder how Vidual GC gets a look in there?

Answer (score 0):

All responses here relates to PermGen problem that happens because of several restarts of web-app, but in this case the problem already happens on first deployment after tomcat restart, so it can't be the problem of ClassLoader's references or commons-logging.

Comment: This is not an answer, you should edit the original question and add this information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on jdk6 then you can use the jconsole app to monitor the memory usage of the application and investigate further.

Another avenue to pursue is to use a profiler, I use JProfiler, and take a look at the application with that. It will tell you exactly where the problem is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same problem, and I've [read that](http://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CEkQFjAF&url=http://forum.springframework.org/printthread.php?t=21383&pp=40&rct=j&q=permgen%20cough%20tomcat&ei=E_KKTtPCIs2BhQeise3bAw&usg=AFQjCNGNDzXUYx2fnFawWj6yKyQlAbSUhw&sig2=F6P8WtLL_zkVnveQcwIGNw&cad=rja) Tomcat is the culprit in this situation.

Then I switched to jetty instead and everything turned out great, and the app deploys/runs as expected.
So if tomcat is not a must, then I'd suggest Jetty.