# How to handle PermGen space exception in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, permgen

I am getting a PermGen Space Exception whenever I deploy my web application.
I tried some JVm option in [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) but still unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: You should take a look at the questions already asked in this regard. 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error

2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473011/recurring-permgen-in-tomcat-6

Then it is only a matter of configuring the Tomcat installation in Netbeans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this JVM parameter: `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m` (or `256m` or `512m`). Here's a related [article](http://my.opera.com/karmazilla/blog/2007/03/13/good-riddance-permgen-outofmemoryerror) as well that lists some other useful JVM options.

Comment: thanks for your reply,
i tried this option,but still showing the same issue.

Comment: Did you try the other options as well in the article (-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled, -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled)?

Comment: I agree, Taylor L. Also, upping permgen just delays the inevitable.

Comment: Note: the link here no longer seems valid