# Java Class (PermGen) Memory Leak (Web Applications) - Generic Solution?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, permgen

I have a perm gen memory leak, that I know. Profiling using jvisualvm shows that when doing hot deployment (e.g. stop and start an application without killing the JVM, in tomcat, WebSphere, WebLogic etc) - the PermGen space is constantly increasing.

After reading, using jhat, and other advanced tools I realized that I probably have a reference to the `WebAppClassLoader` from a class somewhere in its parent class loaders.

I couldn't pin it down even though I did some massive JavaScript based queries on jhat

Isn't there a simple utility that finds out who is responsible for you class loader to not be garbage collected (thus allowing garbage collection of classes loaded by it)?

I tried JProfiler, jvisualvm, jhat, and a lot of Google

to all the LMGTFY friends - I've spent about a day and a half reading forums with step by steps instructions, no luck. I'm looking for a utility or code that outputs:

Object X of class Y is the sole GC root that keeps your classes from being removed.

Comment: what information did JProfiler give you? What objects stay when you explicitely call the garbage collector?

Comment: and how are you doing hot deployment (on tomcat) ?

Comment: @Bozho - using Tomcat Manager, pressing stop / start.


The objects that stay are the WebAppClassLoader, and all of it's loaded classes. the closest GC root hunt didn't give practical results.

Comment: aha. Well, that fails for everyone, not only for you :) use it only in development

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an unsatisfiying but easy solution: Don't hotdeploy in production environments. You could setup a cluster of two servlet containers and them update one at a time with a restart.

Comment: This is a pretty common pattern for high availability deployment architectures.

Comment: So how to convince the client? Is there a white paper describing this pattern?

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer. I am having the same problem on a local test environment, and I'd really like to avoid restarting the Tomcat if I can.

Comment: If it's a test environment - just crank up MaxPermGen until you can do it `x` times without crashing

Comment: Isn't it better to attempt to find the cause of the leak in your code? It is after all a mistake. Shouldn't I want to avoid making the same mistake in the future? Is this really the answer that would be recommended by experienced programmers?

Answer (score 5):

The realities of frequent redeployments...
Best you can do is increase the size of perm gen using -XX:MaxPermSize=256m. This may buy you some  redeployments more per jvm restart.
Or read on at http://my.opera.com/karmazilla/blog/2007/03/15/permgen-strikes-back

Beware that if the classloaders can't be gc-ed at all, fiddling with the jvm won't help at all. You'd better forget about frequent deployments, especially in production, for dev it's handy, nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

I used the method from this site and it helped.
http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space/

Comment: Thank you. It definitely solved my problem ( tomcat + spring + spring data graph )

Answer (score 1):

Few pointers here as well,
http://minmaxmim.blogspot.com/2010/01/javalangoutofmemoryerror-java-heap.html

also  check the javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space article.