# Why am I receiving java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space error?>

Tags: java, glassfish-3

I am developing an application using java and I am using GlassFish Serve 3+ as my container, some times when I run my application run into the following error, I am wondering what would be the reason,

```
type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: PWC1243: Filter execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 logs.
```

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683434/permgen-space-error-glassfish-server) .Somebody has asked a similar question.

Comment: It won't help with a memory leak - but it may be interesting to note that Java 8 has done away with Perm Gen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)

> Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because
>   it is out of memory, and no more memory could be made available by the
>   garbage collector. OutOfMemoryError objects may be constructed by the
>   virtual machine as if suppression were disabled and/or the stack trace
>   was not writable.

Check if you are creating too many objects using the `new` keyword. Locations to look for are loops, recursive methods among others.

Answer (score 0):

Set the PermSize in JAVA_OPTS environment variable [used to allocate memory to Java JVM]
If it is already set, increase the MaxPermSize

eg:

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:PermSize=128m"

More detailed info about JAVA_OPTS is here

http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/projects/THREDDS/tech/tds4.3/reference/JavaOptsSummary.html

Comment: Initial PermSize won't help. Max will delay the problem if you are having a leak.

Answer (score 0):

I know in NetBeans' default glassfish configuration, it doesn't tell the server to clean up its unused classes. Try the following solution:

[Glassfish PermGen out of Memory Errors](http://blog.maurus.be/2012/10/15/glassfish-permgen-out-of-memory-errors/)