# why webappclassloader is not garbage collected ?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a web service developped by spring/hibernate, and when I do  deployment and undeployment on Tomcat 7 many times, I get an outOfMemoryError PermGen Memory leak.

By using java VisualVM, I noticed that the previous webappClassLoader are still kept in JVM, so they are not garbage collected.

What can be the reasons of this problem ?

How can I detect which objects still have reference to the application class loader or any object loaded by it ?

Thanks,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683434/permgen-space-error-glassfish-server/7685644#7685644

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that you have a memory leak. From experience, this is most likely to be in your web application or a library it is using. It is also possible, but unlikely, that you have found a memory leak in Tomcat.

The short version for tracking down the memory leak is:

- Start Tomcat
- Undeploy and redeploy the problematic application once
- Use a profiler to examine the heap
- Look for an instances of the WebappClassLoader
- Find the one that is strongly held but has an attribute of started = false
- Trace the GC roots for that instance of the WebappClassLoader
- That will point to your memory leak

Finding the root cause of the memory leak might be a little harder.

For a fuller explanation of how to track down this sort of memory leak and what might cause them see this presentation: http://people.apache.org/~markt/presentations/2010-08-05-Memory-Leaks-JavaOne-60mins.pdf

Comment: this would get +1 just because of the presentation link. Then I noticed you are actually its author. Best material I've read on the subject and I now wonder how come it's the first time I read it. Thank you :)

Comment: thanks ! as you said I got instances of WebappClassLoader which have started = false. the problem is to trace the GC root ! I suspect a TimerThread which isn't stopped ! so how can I do for stop this thread after web app undeployment ?

Comment: Use a ServletContextListener and stop the thread in the contextDestroyed() event.