# Tomcat Server Crashed Instantly

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat7, hibernate-annotations

Tomcat Server crashed instantly while i run my application.

I have done a spring mvc application with hibernate framework.I am new hibernate and spring mvc.

I deployed my app to tomcat server.. It runs only short time.

when i am going to check tomcat log files.

i got this error when my app not load in tomcat server.

log files in tomcat server

localhost.24-1-14

```
Jan 28, 2014 4:39:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/travellogs] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space] with root cause
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

some times i got this error "Too Many Connections"

I don't know how to resolve it. I think my code contain memory leakage..

This is my jdbc.properties file

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kqtravellog?autoReconnect=true


jdbc.username=kqtravellog
jdbc.password=123asd!@#


jdbc.maxConnections=25

jdbc.acquireIncrement=5
jdbc.minPoolSize=25
jdbc.maxPoolSize=1000
jdbc.maxIdleTime=36000

jdbc.numHelperThreads=100


# Property that determines the Hibernate dialect
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

dispatcher servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.kqics" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="userService" class="com.sample.dao.traveldao">
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver1" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="basename" value="views"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
    </bean>

    <import resource="db-config.xml" />

</beans>
```

db-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location"><value>/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties</value></property>
    </bean>


<bean id="dataSourceBean" lazy-init="true"       class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">

        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />


        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${jdbc.acquireIncrement}" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${jdbc.minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jdbc.maxPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${jdbc.maxIdleTime}" />
        <property name="numHelperThreads" value="${jdbc.numHelperThreads}" />

    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
                 p:dataSource-ref="dataSourceBean"
                 p:packagesToScan="com.kqics" >

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <!--   <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop> --> 
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ><ref bean="sessionFactory"/></property>

    </bean>


</beans>
```

This is my dao implementation

```
public class kqtraveldao {

    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        try {
            hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);

        } catch (Exception w) {
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void addnewvehicle(kqvehicle obj) {

        hibernateTemplate.save(obj);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<kqvehicle> fetchallvehicle() {

        List<kqvehicle> li=hibernateTemplate.find("from kqvehicle");
        return li;
    }

    @Override
    public void addnewvehicletariff(kqvehicletariff obj, String tariff) {

        try
        {
        hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory()
        .openSession()
        .createSQLQuery("insert into "+tariff+" values(?,?,?,?,?)")
        .setParameter(0, obj.getTid())
        .setParameter(1, obj.getVehicletype())
        .setParameter(2, obj.getRupees())
        .setParameter(3, obj.getDateupto())
        .setParameter(4, obj.getDatetimedetermined())
        .executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().close();
        }


    }
```

Service class

@Service
public class kqtravellogservice implements ikqtravellogservice {

```
@Autowired
ikqtraveldao iDao;

@Transactional
public void serviceaddnewvehicle(kqvehicle obj) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    iDao.addnewvehicle(obj);

}

@Transactional
public List<kqvehicle> servicefetchallvehicle() {

    return iDao.fetchallvehicle();
}

@Transactional
public void serviceaddnewvehicletariff(kqvehicletariff obj,String tariff) {

    iDao.addnewvehicletariff(obj,tariff);

}
```

}

These methods are i used to develop a appln.

i dont know where i find memory leakage.. please advice me.....

Comment: What makes you say there is a leak? Have you tried increasing the permgen space? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003855/increase-permgen-space

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is increase your PermGen space. Its easy. If you're using Eclipse, just go to Run > Run Configuration. Select your server, go to Arguments and put this after:

-XX:MaxPermSize=512m