# Permgen space error for springs application

Tags: java, apache, exception, tomcat, permgen

I have one simple Login and logout springs application which is throwing exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space again and again. I tried to change VM option of application in my NetBeans IDE but its not working.
I made following changes:

```
-Xmx1024m
```

and

```
-Xmx512m
```

Every time my application is running 2-3 times then throwing this exception. is it because of my code or any other configurations? How can i solve it?

Comment: Use option for increasing max permgen space. More info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003855/increase-permgen-space

Comment: How are you running Tomcat?

Comment: @Bart : clicking on run button of IDE. Tomcat is getting started automatically

Comment: I don't know Netbeans but there must be some runner configuration that supports that button. It's a good idea to investigate there and try the VM options presented by the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

The `PermGen` memory space sits outside of the heap, so changing `Xmx` won't help.

Try the following: `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m` or some larger value if that's not enough.

Hope this helps,

Will