# Apache Tomcat 7 - PS Perm Gen out of memory

Tags: apache, tomcat

The used size of the PS Perm Gen Memory Pool increases with every request.
I think its not because of my webapp, because when I refresh http://www.myurl.de/manager/ (the build in tomcat manager) the used Perm Gen size gets 0,1mb/10 refreshes. When I go to my webapp its 0,2mb each request.

When the Perm Gen max. size is reached I have to restart Tomcat.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is definitely leaking resources.

I suggest you review your code (opening/closing database connections), or any other Objects that can be released between requests.

Based on the given information I cannot suggest anything further.

Don't forget that you can always [increase the JVM's Perm Gen Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003855/increase-permgen-space) using the command (value in MB):

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

...but thats only a temporary solution.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but why does the used perm gen size grow if i only call the tomcat manager (http://www.myurl.de/manager/) many times?

Comment: I just upgraded to java 8 and tomcat 8 because there is no Perm Gen Memory. Hope it works...

But now I have a new max. weid problem