# I am continuously getting this java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, netbeans

When I deploy and run my project in netbeans, I am getting this error.. And even after setting up JAVA_OPTS and CATALINA_OPTS in environmental variables as well as in netbeans 'VM options' as -Xms512m -Xmx2048m, I am getting same error.. Please, help me out to sort it out..

```
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Comment: increase permgen space

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003855/increase-permgen-space

Comment: where to give this one ...   -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m

Comment: I already set up the permgen space as '-Xms512m -Xmx2048m'

Comment: 2048m perm gen size is way too much. Default is 64m, try increasing it to 128m (like -XX:MaxPermSize=128m). And with "-Xm..." you don't set your perm gen size, but the heap size. Read the answers to the question I linked above.

Comment: Still I am getting, this error..........                                               SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/datainput] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space] with root cause
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Comment: Can you show us the complete list of VM options you use when starting the Java VM?

Comment: This is the VM option that I set up in Netbeans.. -Xms512m -Xmx1024m... And also I created setenv.bat file in apache-tomcat/bin/setenv.bat and added '-Xms512m -Xmx1024m' but, still it is not working properly

Comment: and also I am getting this error too....                                                           Could not complete request
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Comment: Did you read *any* of my comments? -Xm... does *not* affect your perm gen space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you start Tomcat from netbeans the -XX:MaxPerm... must go to server setting not JVM settings (or JAVA_OPTS).

- go to sevices tab on the left
- expand servers and right click on your tomcat
- on the Platform tab, provide the necessary settings under VM options (for example -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx2048m )