# Java continuous GC, ParOldGen exhausted

Tags: java, garbage-collection, google-cloud-platform

We have a large Java app running on Google Cloud Managed VMs (which limits our ability to control the JVM tuning parameters I think).

We have many millions of objects (some 15GB) in RAM.

While doing a task which may involve creating tens of thousands more objects (parsing a huge Excel) the system freezes for many minutes probably due to Garbage Collection.

We noticed that overall we are not low on RAM but `ParOldGen` seems 99% used.  Any suggestions how to avoid this please?

```
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 6083072K, used 267497K [0x000000064eb00000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 6078464K, 4% used [0x000000064eb00000,0x000000065f03a438,0x00000007c1b00000)
  from space 4608K, 0% used [0x00000007c1b00000,0x00000007c1b00000,0x00000007c1f80000)
  to   space 528384K, 0% used [0x00000007dfc00000,0x00000007dfc00000,0x0000000800000000)
 ParOldGen       total 14198272K, used 14197939K [0x00000002ec180000, 0x000000064eb00000, 0x000000064eb00000)
  object space 14198272K, 99% used [0x00000002ec180000,0x000000064eaacc60,0x000000064eb00000)
 PSPermGen       total 65536K, used 50669K [0x00000002e1b80000, 0x00000002e5b80000, 0x00000002ec180000)
  object space 65536K, 77% used [0x00000002e1b80000,0x00000002e4cfb640,0x00000002e5b80000)
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could connect to the JVM with VisualGC.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003855/increase-permgen-space

Comment: Thanks but running on a Managed VM (inside a Docker environment created by Google) I'm not sure we can run Visual GC or play with parameters like -XX:MaxPermSize

Answer (score 2):

As described in [this article on Java GC](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-java-garbage-collection#cms-gc), ParOldGen (or Concurrent Old Gen (Mark Sweep) GC) can take a long time during its "stop the world" phase when dealing with lots of fragmentation in memory, something that you'd expect to see in such an object-heavy pattern. Perhaps this is worth reading as an explanation of what's happening?

As to [increasing the heap size](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4742/abeik/index.html), this can be done with JVM options, which can be manipulated when using Custom Runtimes / Flexible Environment apps. You can also [configure the amount of memory each instance will have](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-appengine-web-xml#resource-settings).

Finally, you can also [select which GC algorithms should run](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) using JVM options. You might find the app performs better without ParOldGen at all.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this will be an option for you, but you could switch to Custom Runtimes:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/custom-runtimes

With that you have more control of how your server will run and you'll be able to tweak JVM params.