# -XX:MaxPermSize=128m: command not found when setting MaxPermSize on linux server

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

> Getting this kind of error on linux server  in my project when i run my spring-hibernate project 
>   i read the

[Increase permgen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003855/increase-permgen-space)

someone replied to execute

```
 -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

> to increase of MaxPermSize  but when i execute this command in  in my
>   project under directory of classes   i got an error

```
[root@server classes]# -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
-bash: -XX:MaxPermSize=128m: command not found

Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

How  can I set MaxPermSize  only for one particular project  as I am working on live server some projects are live on that server so please suggest me right solution so that I can set MaxPermSize on live server

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood the answer on the original question.

When you run a Java program, you use a command like:

```
java [JVM arguments] ClassName [program arguments]
```

The `--XX:MaxPermSize=128m` part goes in the "JVM arguments" part - it is a directive to the JVM to allocate 128m of memory to the PermGen.

So you are supposed to edit the `java` command in your script and not put that argument on a separate line.

You should also consider upgrading to Java 8, in which Permgen no longer exists.

Comment: it means to set MaxPermSize 
i have to execute command like

java --XX:MaxPermSize=128m ClassName [program arguments]

can u tell me what should i write in program arguments

Comment: @KunalBatra [program arguments] are the arguments the program expects as input.

Comment: okk 
i have executed 
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -server -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"

on the server for  now my projects are  working fine 
thanx for your reply sir :)

Answer (score 1):

`-XX:MaxPermSize=128m` is a JVM argument, not a `bash` command.