# Tomcat CMS PermGen keeps growing with cargo deployment and hangs at 100%

Tags: java, tomcat, cargo

So my Tomcat CMS PermGen keeps growing 20-30MB when a new .war file is deployed. At 99% PermGen the deployer (https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/) will just get stuck, until I restart Tomcat and cancel the Maven build. I have tried JVM options like `-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled` and `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` but the CMS PermGen just keeps growing.

Comment: Did you try to increase your PermGen? see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003855/increase-permgen-space)

Comment: I did, but that's just postponing the crash.

Comment: What version of Tomcat do you use ? The Tomcat team worked (in T7+) on a "bug" that caused some JDK classes to reference classes from the deployed webapps ; and as a class has a link to its Classloader, and a Classloader to all the classes it loaded, it actually prevented the whole webapp to be properly collected. Hence, as hot-reloads occured, the memory was getting full and Tomcat had to be restarted. This should have been corrected / mitigated in versions 7+.

Comment: It is currently running _Apache Tomcat/7.0.56 (Debian)_