# Unable to open maven in eclipse while using OpenJDK 7

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-mars, azul-zulu

I have started migration from oracle JDK 7 from Open JDK 7. While opening eclipse it starts properly. When I go to Windows > Preferences > Maven and open maven windows in eclipse, it just hang up and throws below error.

I have tried to increase Xmx and Xms size in eclipse.ini but every time eclipse throws below exception.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with eclipse? Does the eclipse missed any plugin ? or Do I need to upgrade maven plugin?

My development environment as below

- Windows 7 (64-bit)
- OpenJDK 7 (64-bit) Zulu build
- Eclipse mars (64-bit)
- Maven (3.5.2)

Thanks for the help in advance.

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-02-20 12:32:04.982
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core (947).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.MavenPluginActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2595)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2895)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceNode.createPage(WorkbenchPreferenceNode.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1300)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.createPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9$1.run(PreferenceDialog.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:877)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:874)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1243)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1269)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1$2.run(OpenStrategy.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.open(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(OpenPreferencesAction.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
    at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingBuilder.<init>(AbstractBindingBuilder.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingBuilder.<init>(BindingBuilder.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.bind(Elements.java:288)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.bind(Elements.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.ElementAnalyzer$1.configure(ElementAnalyzer.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:253)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.ElementAnalyzer.<clinit>(ElementAnalyzer.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule.configure(WireModule.java:74)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:253)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:135)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:481)
Root exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
    at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingBuilder.<init>(AbstractBindingBuilder.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingBuilder.<init>(BindingBuilder.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.bind(Elements.java:288)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.bind(Elements.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.ElementAnalyzer$1.configure(ElementAnalyzer.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:253)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.ElementAnalyzer.<clinit>(ElementAnalyzer.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule.configure(WireModule.java:74)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:253)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:135)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:481)
```

Comment: It is a PermGen issue, so please see [Increase PermGen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003855/increase-permgen-space).

Comment: @MartinFreidank I have tried to increase Xmx and Xms size in eclipse.ini up to 2 GB but still the problem exists.

Comment: I recognized that, so that is why I linked the other topic. You have to increase -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Comment: @MartinFreidank Thanks for the help I am going to upvote your previous comment. Also I am going to answer below question to clarify more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse 3.3 and above supports an argument to the launcher: --launcher.XXMaxPermSize. On Windows, Eclipse ships with the following lines in the eclipse.ini file:

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m

With the above arguments, if the VM being used is a Sun VM and there is not already a -XX:MaxPermSize=(VM argument), then the launcher will automatically add -XX:MaxPermSize=256m to the list of VM arguments being used. The Eclipse launcher is only capable of identifying **Sun VMs** on Windows.

The option --launcher.XXMaxPermSize is something that the launcher reads (not the JVM); it tells the launcher to automatically size the JVM's perm gen if it (the launcher) detects a Sun JVM that supports that option.

If you are using other JVM than **non-Sun JVM's could fail because they don't understand that option**, you must have to define -XX:MaxPermSize= (256m or 512m whatever fit best) under -vmargs

e.g

-vmargs 
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Hope this help others.