# How to avoid Perm Gem space exception in JBoss server?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I deploy my J2EE application after making some changes to the code.

At maximum of 4 times I can deploy the EAR file into the server without restarting the JBoss server. After the 4th deployment if I deploy one more time it throws PermGem space exception.

I don't what this exception is. I restart the server then everything works fine.
Any idea why the Jboss server throws PermGem space exception after 4 deployments ?And Why it occurs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an explanation about PermGem space [here](http://www.freshblurbs.com/explaining-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space). [Here](http://blog.mangar.com.br/?p=59) are some JBoss specific instructions.

You could have a [classloader leak](http://blogs.oracle.com/fkieviet/entry/classloader_leaks_the_dreaded_java) in your code that causes this. Or you have a huge code base with many dependencies and haven't configured the PermGem space appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to enable the sweeping of the permgen area, which is not covered in the previous answer.

[This answer provides details to do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error)