# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space in tomcat with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

i get this exception frequently when running my app on tomcat using eclipse:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1850)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:890)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1354)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1850)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:890)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1354)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1650)
    at com.spacerdv.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.getUserDetails(UserDaoImpl.java:170)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

try to raise perm space, add following parameters to vm start-up

-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

also add **-XX:MaxPermSize=256m** to Tomcat in Eclipse: `Server > Open Launch Configuration > Arguments`

**Update (in 2014):** take a look [here at this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074164/what-is-the-use-of-metaspace-in-java-8) about [the new Java 8 Metaspace.](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.ie/2013/02/java-8-from-permgen-to-metaspace.html)

and take a look here:

[How to deal with “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error)

Comment: On Netbeans this parameters can be added in: Services > Servers > Apache Tomcat (right click) > Properties > Platform > VM Options

Comment: also  you might wanna add `-server -Xmx1024m`

Comment: This solution only postpones the problem. My tomcat usually runs at MaxPermSize=512m and still exhausts the PermSize. It happens when changed code gets autodeployed too often. My workaround is to restart tomcat explicitly every once in a while.

Answer (score 21):

You can configure these arguments for eclipse:

"To solve this I stopped the server in Eclipse.  Double clicked on the server in the *Servers* tab to open the Overview page for the server.  Clicked on *Open Launch Configuration* and then on the *Arguments* tab.

I added the following VM arguments :

```
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
```

ref to http://malcolmmallia.com/malcblog/?p=60

Comment: Thank you! Our team was having some issues on our QA and production servers after changing web service stacks, and these two options fixed our PermGen issues. (For now at least.)

Answer (score 5):

I got this problem today as well. It happened completely out of the blue. Yesterday I've updated JDK/JRE from 1.6.0_13 to 1.6.0_21 to fix a Glassfish 3.0.1 specific issue and Eclipse suddenly broke with those `OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` errors. After (incorrectly) ranting on the Glassfish plugin and concluding that the issue wasn't fixed after cleaning the workspace metadata, it turns out that this is caused by the change of JVM vendor string from "Sun" to "Oracle" since 1.6.0_20. Eclipse didn't recognize the new JVM vendor and thus didn't apply the VM arguments as specified in `eclipse.ini`.

This was reported as Eclipse issue [319514](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=319514) and the Eclipse boys quickly released a [patch](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=174008). Until they get it fixed more permanently, the workaround is indeed to add the following lines to the `eclipse.ini`:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

So, if you recently did a JVM update, it might be worth to take a look to it.