# What's mean PermGen Space?

Tags: android, eclipse

In eclipse when I want to import an Android method (onDestroy(), onPause()...) I got an error with only message PermGen Space. What's mean this, and what can I do to make it workable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question [discusses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179141/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-in-tomcat-with-eclipse) about the problem. It is about Tomcat, but I believe the solution will be the same (increase permgen heap size).

Comment: OK thanks, I will make it, but Where I need to add this -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m? Sorry, but I'm now learning andorid.

Comment: See http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_permgen_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F