# How does Metaspace and Native Area memory gets managed in Java?

Tags: java, memory, java-8, jvm, metaspace

From what I have understood, the **Native Area** inside the JVM is completely off-limits for the Garbage Collector. Inside the Native Area, in which **Metaspace** is located. In the aforementioned Metaspace, we have areas such as **Constant Pool, Field and Method Data**.

Since the Native Area is managed by the C++ memory management (or at least that's how I understand it), how come that Metaspace, that is not of a fixed size, instead grows dynamically, depending on how much memory is needed, will not run out of the memory? Is Garbage Collector allowed in the Metaspace, but not the rest of Native Area? Is C++ managing the memory there dynamically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how come that Metaspace, that is not of a fixed size

You can limit the size by setting value for `MaxMetaSpaceSize` on command line.

> ...will not run out of the memory?

Yes, it actually does run out of memory. When it exceeds usage of available memory and will get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace` exception.

> Is Garbage Collector allowed in the Metaspace

Yes. The GC will collect both the Java Heap and the Metaspace, but not the native heap. It is managed by whoever native code owns it.

Reference :

[3.2 Understand the OutOfMemoryError Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html)

[About G1 Garbage Collector, Permanent Generation and Metaspace](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/about-g1-garbage-collector,-permanent-generation-and-metaspace)

Comment: Instead of `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace`, won't it be `java.lang.StackOverFlowError`?

Comment: @ForInfinity Technically, both are different `StackOverFlowError` doesn't means `OutOfMemory` instead you have exceeded the stack size.

Comment: Additionally, one major point remains unanswered, is GC allowed in other areas of the **Native Area**, other than the Metaspace?

Comment: @ForInfinity the (not uncommon) confusion stems from using the term “garbage collector” for two entirely different things. Does the garbage collector traverse objects in the Metaspace? *No*. Does the garbage collector’s activity allow reclaiming memory inside the Metaspace? *Yes*. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26484392/2711488)