# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am getting this `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` Exception. I am using Eclipse Juno and Tomcat 7.0. This Exception occurs at least once in every 10-15 Minutes in a console. How to resolve it?

```
Feb 25, 2016 10:23:23 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory destroyBean
SEVERE: Destroy method on bean with name 'mvcUrlPathHelper' threw an exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:375)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:242)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:925)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:997)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:547)

Feb 25, 2016 10:23:24 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory destroyBean
SEVERE: Destroy method on bean with name 'mvcPathMatcher' threw an exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Comment: Whats written in destroy method of bean 'mvcUrlPathHelper'?

Comment: what is the size u defined for jvm in Tomcat ??

Comment: @PhanindraGopishetty mvcUrlPathHelper??

Comment: @VikrantKashyap where can i check jvm size??

Comment: sorry It's an internal framework bean. Try looking up for eclipse.ini file and change the memory allocated
-Xmx512m

Comment: @PhanindraGopishetty its already having Xmx512m,, should i change it to  Xmx1024m

Comment: yes go ahead and increase the value

Comment: @PhanindraGopishetty i changed to 1024,, its giving pop up error while starting eclipse called "Failed to Create JVM"

Comment: How much of free Ram is available? What is your ram size?

Comment: @PhanindraGopishetty 2 GB, free 400MB

Comment: ok. So you must be trying to load a lot of data with such small amount of free memory. 
You will have to do some optimization. Get few records at a time using hibernate queries instead of getting whole data at once.
Example- query.setFirstResult(0);
query.setMaxResults(10);

Comment: @PhanindraGopishetty ok ill try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104511/discussion-between-santosh-jadi-and-phanindra-gopishetty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead making changes in eclipse.ini, its better to install [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

I Installed Java 8 and now I am not getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` Exception.

Answer (score 4):

**What is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space?**

**Ans:**

The `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` message indicates that the Permanent Generation’s area in memory is exhausted.

Any Java applications is allowed to use a limited amount of memory. The exact amount of memory your particular application can use is specified during application startup.

Java memory is separated into different regions which can be seen in the following image:
[image]

**What will be the solution for this error PermGen space?**

**Ans:**

For Heap,

```
export JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
```

For Permgen,

```
JVM_ARGS="-XX:PermSize=512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

You can give also additional section

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

You can also give more additional section :)

```
-XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:SurvivorRatio=2 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=128 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0 -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=10 -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

**Metaspace: A new memory space is born**

The `JDK 8 HotSpot JVM` is now using native memory for the representation of class metadata and is called `Metaspace`; similar to the Oracle `JRockit` and IBM `JVM's`.

The good news is that it means no more `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` problems and no need for you to tune and monitor this memory space anymore.

Related Link:

1. https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space
2. https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/permgen-space
3. http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.in/2011/07/most-complete-list-of-xx-options-for.html#UseConcMarkSweepGC
4. https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/12/decoding-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space.html
5. http://www.javavillage.in/reasons-outofmemory-permespace.php
6. [Dealing with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error)

Java 8 Links

1. [What is the use of MetaSpace in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074164/what-is-the-use-of-metaspace-in-java-8)
2. https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/about_g1_garbage_collector_permanent
3. https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/metaspace
4. https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to configure Java for more PermGenSpace but I would recommend to migrate to Java 1.8 runtime instead. Install Java 8 SDK and add two lines like

```
-vm
D:/jdk8/jre/bin/javaw.exe
```

to eclipse.ini. This problem is fixed starting from Java 1.8 and does not longer require any hacks.