# Applications is slowing with metaspace growth

Tags: performance, grails, groovy, java-8, metaspace

I just moved from grails 2.4.3 to grails 2.5.6 and from Java 7 to Java 8.
I'm trying to set optimal metaspace size in my app.

Actual metaspace size has big impact on application performance:

Used metaspace and response avg time:

- 200 MB - 339 ms
- 300 MB - 380 ms
- 400 MB - 430 ms
- 500 MB - 460 ms
- 600 MB - 530 ms

Metaspace is growing from application start to 620MB in 90 minutes.

This is my actual gc settings:

```
 -Xms14G -Xmx14G\
 -XX:+UseG1GC\
 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8\
 -XX:ConcGCThreads=4\
 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200\
 -XX:+UseLargePages\
 -XX:+UseLargePagesInMetaspace\
 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch\
 -XX:InitialBootClassLoaderMetaspaceSize=512M\
 -XX:MetaspaceSize=512M\
 -XX:MinMetaspaceExpansion=8M\
 -XX:MaxMetaspaceExpansion=32M\
 -XX:+UseStringDeduplication\
 -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled\
 -XX:-TieredCompilation\
```

When MaxMetaspaceSize was set to 512M then after few hours of running my app is slowing down 1 or 2 times for hour. Respons time is around 10 seconds then.

Anyone had such problem? In yours applications metaspace has such impact on performance?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions like "Anyone had such problem? In yours applications metaspace has such impact on performance?" are not useful to have on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Have you profiled your app?

I'd say that [Metaspace garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074164/what-is-the-use-of-metaspace-in-java-8) was involved here. It collects dead classes and classloaders and it's triggered once the class metadata usage reaches the MaxMetaspaceSize (which was narrowed by `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize`).

Comment: When metaspace riches max value and gc is clearing metaspace avg time jumps to 1-10s. It happens 1-2 times per hour.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/b7UAmOR
on first chart is avg time and second metaspace size.
As you can see without working gc avg time is growing.