# Java : how to check current Perm / PermGen Size?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-crash

Yesterday when I was running the WebLogic Application Server 11g installer, I encountered a OutOfMemory error, so I Googled for the answer:

```
java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar wls1032_generic.jar
```

Everything worked :)

However, when I think twice about the solution, I might have made a mistake: How could I know the current settings of those? I certainly need to check their values before overriding them, right?

Any thoughts?

**Related link:** People in [another thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error) suggested trial and error approach, which is not ideal.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a 32 or 64 bit OS? There are limits on the 32-bit version that may be too restrictive on how much memory you can use.

Comment: @James Black: Fortunately/Unfortunately, 64-bit :)

Comment: The questions in the title and the description are ambigous. The current size can be checked with jmap and the current setting can be checked with jmap and jinfo.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can check the values of any JVM flags of a running JVM by using the `jinfo.exe` utility.

`%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jinfo.exe -flag <flagName> <pid>`

so to check the value of `-XX:PermSize` JVM option you can run

`%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jinfo.exe -flag PermSize <pid>`

Answer (score 23):

You can use `jmap` at [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html), it's JVM Heap Dump Tool.

for example:

```
jmap -heap 5900
```

It will print:

```
Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   MaxHeapSize      = 989855744 (944.0MB)
   NewSize          = 1310720 (1.25MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 17592186044415 MB
   OldSize          = 5439488 (5.1875MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 21757952 (20.75MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 85983232 (82.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 242352128 (231.125MB)
   used     = 9196056 (8.770042419433594MB)
   free     = 233156072 (222.3549575805664MB)
   3.79450185805672% used
From Space:
   capacity = 41877504 (39.9375MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 41877504 (39.9375MB)
   0.0% used
To Space:
   capacity = 42663936 (40.6875MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 42663936 (40.6875MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 80609280 (76.875MB)
   used     = 34187936 (32.604156494140625MB)
   free     = 46421344 (44.270843505859375MB)
   42.41191088668699% used
PS Perm Generation
   capacity = 85393408 (81.4375MB)
   used     = 63472624 (60.53221130371094MB)
   free     = 21920784 (20.905288696289062MB)
   74.32965317416539% used
```

It gets memory information (including PermGen).`5900` is the process id of Java.

Answer (score 7):

You can use something like VisualVM, http://java.dzone.com/articles/best-kept-secret-jdk-visualvm&default=false&zid=159&browser=16&mid=0&refresh=0, to monitor your memory usage and you will see the max by where it peaks, and it will give you specific info as to which part of memory is actually full, so you can better optimize your environment.

You may find that some part of memory that you don't think about is actually filling up, and by monitoring it you can see what you need to do to get better performance.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to get PermGen information is:

```
kill -3 JAVA_PID
```

It gets thread dump and memory information (including  PermGen). Example output:

```
PSPermGen       total 68864K, used 68808K [0x000000009c600000, 0x00000000a0940000, 0x00000000a1800000)
```

For some reason *jinfo* did not work when I needed it. It returned:

```
Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
```

There are few possible causes of the above and one of them may be explicit declaration of the *java.io.tmpdir* as described at https://www.permeance.com.au/web/terry.mueller/home/-/blogs/unable-to-open-socket-file-target-process-not-responding-or-hotspot-vm-not-loaded

Comment: It's possible that `jinfo` didn't work as you weren't running it as the same user as the JVM. Try running `jinfo` as root/Administrator