# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: java, tomcat6, permgen

i'm getting the following error
"http-9000-5" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space.

My application using axis2.I increased the heap size 1024mb.But its not working.What would be the problem.Solution please

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Tomcat as a Server of Eclipse, go to Server view, then double click on Tomcat, then "Open Launch Configuration", go to Arguments tab, and after setting -Dcatalina.base="" put this

```
-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:PermSize=128m
```

Answer (score 16):

PermGen and heap size are different from each other.

You need to increase permgen space like this:

```
-XX:PermSize=256m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

add this flags.

Also look at this: [explaining-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space](http://www.freshblurbs.com/explaining-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space) and this: [how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error)

Hope this helps.

Comment: These options are explained a bit here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#PerformanceTuning

Answer (score 15):

you need to set something in your tomcat argument

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-server -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m
-XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
```

Note:XX:MaxPermSize=256m

- [Read more](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space/)

Comment: Remember to put this in a `setenv` script in your tomcat/bin/ directory. For *nix use a `setenv.sh` script with `export JAVA_OPTS="......"` and for Windows use a `setenv.bat` script with `set JAVA_OPTS=.....`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to raising the PermGen size, try enabling permgen garbage collection with

```
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the ram allocation for your JVM. It should help.

Fix for eclipse: You can configure this in eclipse preference as follows

Windows -> Preferences ( on mac its: eclipse ->preferences)
Java -> Installed JREs
Select the JRE and click on Edit
on the default VM arguments field type in --Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:PermSize=128m. (or your memory preference,for 1 gb of ram its 1024)
Click on finish or OK.