# Failed to define class org.codehaus.jackson.impl.WriterBasedGenerator Permspace

Tags: json, spring, jakarta-ee, jboss, jackson

Deploy current application and it works fine on one server but get this error on another new installed server:

```
Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'SampleApp'
```

16:10:50,541 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-4) Failed to define class org.codehaus.jackson.impl.WriterBasedGenerator in Module "deployment.application.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Check `module` folder for both application, and both have same valid jackon denpendencies.

So what could be the issue then?

Answer (score 2):

I think, your problem is not related with `Json` or `Jackson`. You have too small default value for `MaxPermSize`.

Helpful links:

- [-XX:MaxPermSize with or without -XX:PermSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356416/xxmaxpermsize-with-or-without-xxpermsize).
- [Tomcat – java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space/).
- [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space in tomcat with eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179141/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-in-tomcat-with-eclipse).
- [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827544/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space).
- [Dealing with “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error).

Comment: Thankyou . I raise to 512M, but still get same out of memory error, original it was 256M, what is the proper size for J2EE?

Comment: Are you sure that you are setting it correctly? Which web server do you use? I am using Tomcat and -XX:MaxPermSize=256m option works for me.

Comment: I am on JBoss, originally it is 256M, set to 512M seems not resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you have same JBoss installation on both servers? Could you check how it configured on working machine?