# Internal Server Error Jasper Report

Tags: java, tomcat, jasper-reports, out-of-memory, jasperserver

I had some issue when running my Jasper report with Apache Tomcat 7.0. Sometimes my report are running well but sometimes it show a 500 Internal Server Error. I do not know what is the problem since this is my first time deal with Jasper report. Please help me how can I solve this error.
Below is from my jasperserver.log

```
2018-08-06 15:47:45,267 ERROR RenderViewExceptionInterceptor,http-bio-8080-exec-1:58 - Internal server error occurred. Please contact your system administrator.
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:972)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.StaticFilesCacheControlFilter.doFilter(StaticFilesCacheControlFilter.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:399)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.IPadSupportFilter.doFilter(IPadSupportFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.JSSwitchUserProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(JSSwitchUserProcessingFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:148)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.UserPreferencesFilter.doFilter(UserPreferencesFilter.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.NullFilter.doFilterHttp(NullFilter.java:44)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.UserPreferencesFilter.doFilter(UserPreferencesFilter.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.logging.filter.BasicLoggingFilter.doFilter(BasicLoggingFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.JSCsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(JSCsrfGuardFilter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.WebAppSecurityFilter.doFilter(WebAppSecurityFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.MultipartRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(MultipartRequestWrapperFilter.java:95)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.encryption.EncryptionFilter.doFilter(EncryptionFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.SessionDecoratorFilter.doFilter(SessionDecoratorFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.P3PFilter.doFilter(P3PFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at feldacms_2_1446014682126_206718.$getStaticMetaClass(calculator_feldacms_2_1446014682126_206718)
    at feldacms_2_1446014682126_206718.<init>(calculator_feldacms_2_1446014682126_206718)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractJavaCompiler.loadEvaluator(JRAbstractJavaCompiler.java:112)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.loadEvaluator(JRAbstractCompiler.java:340)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getEvaluator(JasperCompileManager.java:378)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createCalculator(JRFillDataset.java:462)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createCalculator(JRFillDataset.java:452)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRParameterDefaultValuesEvaluator.evaluateParameterDefaultValues(JRParameterDefaultValuesEvaluator.java:82)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRParameterDefaultValuesEvaluator.evaluateParameterDefaultValues(JRParameterDefaultValuesEvaluator.java:59)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.getReportInputControlsInformation(EngineServiceImpl.java:2503)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.getReportInputControlsInformation(EngineServiceImpl.java:2461)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.getReportInputControlsInformation(EngineServiceImpl.java:2349)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.ReportParametersAction.getControlsInformation(ReportParametersAction.java:618)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.ReportParametersAction.getReportParameterValuesFromRequest(ReportParametersAction.java:452)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.ViewReportAction.executeReport(ViewReportAction.java:490)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.ViewReportAction.runReport(ViewReportAction.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
2018-08-06 15:56:12,618 ERROR ContextLoader,localhost-startStop-1:318 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'diagnosticExporter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-diagnostic.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jasperJMXServer' while setting bean property 'server'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jMXregistry' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-diagnostic.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 10991; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1113)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1671)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jMXregistry' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-diagnostic.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 10991; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 10991; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:328)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:236)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411)
    at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:207)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:122)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:108)
    at java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(LocateRegistry.java:203)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean.getRegistry(RmiRegistryFactoryBean.java:267)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean.getRegistry(RmiRegistryFactoryBean.java:236)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean.getRegistry(RmiRegistryFactoryBean.java:193)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(RmiRegistryFactoryBean.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createServerSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:45)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createServerSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:349)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:667)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:317)
    ... 51 more
2018-08-06 15:56:12,630 ERROR JNDIResourceProvider,localhost-startStop-1:75 - error closing context
javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: Context is read only
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.checkWritable(NamingContext.java:962)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.close(NamingContext.java:762)
    at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.JNDIResourceProvider.close(JNDIResourceProvider.java:72)
    at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.CompositeResourceProvider.close(CompositeResourceProvider.java:56)
    at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactory.initialize(ResourcesFactory.java:163)
    at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactory.<init>(ResourcesFactory.java:92)
    at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactory.<clinit>(ResourcesFactory.java:89)
    at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactoryContextListener.contextInitialized(ResourcesFactoryContextListener.java:23)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1113)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1671)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Just for your reference this is another details:

1. jdk1.7.0_71
2. Apache Tomcat 7.0
3. JasperReports Server Community Project 5.6.1

I dont have any clues what is the problem seem like it is running well sometimes.Any help will greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like your JVM lack memory - try to run it with specific option (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827544/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space)

Comment: There is also a problem of port already used. Could you check you don't have another process using the port `10991`, or that you haven't started the application two times ?

Comment: The first issue reported (_OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space_) is the root cause, and it is understandable that you do not get the failure consistently. See https://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space/ for how to increase it. An alternative approach would be to upgrade to Java 8 - see https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace.