# How can I view the MaxPermSize in JVM?

Tags: java, grails, jvm, permgen

I'm meeting the dreadful [PermGen:Out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error) error when deploying a web-app on TomCat. I have tried many possible solutions, but they don't work out(sometimes it works, usually it doesn't). I wonder if my config in "BuildConfig.groovy" take effect:

```
grails.tomcat.jvmArgs = ["-Xmx1024m", "-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"]
```

Does anyone know someway to view the MaxPermSize actually applied by the JVM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  [JVisualVM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) in the JDK/bin directory to monitor everything about a java process.

Answer (score 4):

In direct answer to your question, java.lang.management.ManagementFactory has method to get information on all of the memory pools used by java, including the PermGen space and other non-heap memory pools:

```
List<MemoryPoolMXBean> memoryPoolMXBeans = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans();

for (MemoryPoolMXBean bean : memoryPoolMXBeans) {
    //Iterate over pools here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of utilities that come in the jsdk i believe - try jstat -gcpermcapacity. Another trick that can sometimes be helpful is ps -fwwwC java (assuming you are running this on a linux box)

Comment: unfortunately I'm working on Windows at this time. How could I try your command?

Comment: You can also use jconsole to connect to your process and monitor the PermGen usage. This should be available on Windows as well.