# Locating code that is filling PermGen with dead Groovy code

Tags: java, memory-leaks, profiling, permgen, jmap

We have had our glassfish instance go down every two weeks for a while with a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`. I increased the PermGen space to 512MB and startet dumping memory usage with `jstat -gc`. After two weeks I came up with the following graph that shows how the PermGen space is steadily increasing (the units on the x-axis are minutes, y-axis are KB).
[image: Graph of increasing PermGen usage]

I tried googling around for some kind of profiling tool that could pinpoint the error and a thread here on SO mentioned jmap, which proved to be quite helpful. Out of the approximately 14000 lines dumped from `jmap -permstats $PID`, approximately 12500 contained `groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader`, pointing to some kind of memory leak from either our own Groovy code or Groovy itself. I have to point out that Groovy constitues less than 1% of the relevant codebase .

Example output below:

```
class_loader    classes bytes   parent_loader   alive?  type

<bootstrap> 3811    14830264      null      live    <internal>
0x00007f3aa7e19d20  20  164168  0x00007f3a9607f010  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x00007f3a7afb4120
0x00007f3aa7c850d0  20  164168  0x00007f3a9607f010  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x00007f3a7afb4120
0x00007f3aa5d15128  21  181072  0x00007f3a9607f010  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x00007f3a7afb4120
0x00007f3aad0b40e8  36  189816  0x00007f3a9d31fbf8  dead    org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader@0x00007f3a7d0caf00
....
```

So how can I proceed to find out more about what code is causing this?

From [this article](http://groovy.dzone.com/news/groovyshell-and-memory-leaks) I infer that our Groovy code is dynamically creating classes somewhere. And from the the dump from jmap I can see that most of the dead objects/classes(?) have the same parent_loader, although I am unsure what that means in this context. I do not know how to proceed from here.

### Addendum

For latecomers, it's worth pointing out that the *accepted answer does not fix the issue*. It simply extends the period needed before rebooting with a tenfold by not storing so much class info. What actually fixed our problems was getting rid of the code that generated it. We used the validation (Design by contract) framework [OVal](http://oval.sourceforge.net/) where one could script custom constraints using Groovy as annotations on methods and classes. Removing the annotations in favor of explicit pre- and post-conditions in plain Java was boring, but it got the job done. I suspect each time an OVal constraint was being checked a new anonymous class was being created and somehow the associated class data was causing a memory leak.

Comment: Does this solution provide any benefit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error

Comment: I haven't solved the problem yet - other things are more pressing, since this can be "solved" by restarting every two weeks, but I have found some good tips on how to pinpoint what is causing the classloader leaks using the Eclipse Memory Analyzer:
http://sites.google.com/site/eclipsebiz/The-Unknown-Generation-Perm

Comment: I'll check back when I have had time to dump the heap space and analyzed it. Seems that there are very few solutions lying around on the interweb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a similar problem (1 week between crashes).  The trouble seems to be that Groovy caches meta methods.  We ended up using this code based on [this discussion](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/ConfigSlurper-GroovyClassLoader-memory-leak-td364279.html) and [bug report](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-2875)

```
GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader();
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(clob.getCharacterStream());
GroovyCodeSource source = new GroovyCodeSource(reader, name, "xb3.Classifier");
Class<?> groovyClass = loader.parseClass(source);
Object possibleClass = groovyClass.newInstance();
if (expectedType.isAssignableFrom(possibleClass.getClass())) {
    classifiers.put((T) possibleClass, name);
}
reader.close();
// Tell Groovy we don't need any meta
// information about these classes
GroovySystem.getMetaClassRegistry().removeMetaClass(possibleClass.getClass());
// Tell the loader to clear out it's cache,
// this ensures the classes will be GC'd
loader.clearCache();
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try this out. Might be a while before I check back with an upvote or answr, though. But not forgotten :)

Comment: Finally had to time to check this out. Got PermGen increase to go from approx 100KB/min to 10KB/min (approximate measure using VisualVM). That at least gives us several weeks more between each restart.

Just needed to add this after script parsing: GroovySystem.getMetaClassRegistry().removeMetaClass(script.getClass());

Comment: For onlookers, the bug report mentioned above places the fix version at 1.5.7 in year 2008.

Answer (score -6):

If you are using Sun JVM change it for IBM JVM , it will works fine i hope :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Eric, but I cannot see how that should help. I know that the IBM JVM has no pre-set static limit on the PermSpace like the JVM, so that it would gradually just increase it as it needed it.

Comment: BUT that still would not fix the memory leak I am experiencing - AFAIK.

Comment: IBM JVM is optimized, source code is different not only for the limits. Your memory leak is caused by external resources memory occupation,

Comment: We already know that, but how would I go about in finding out what part of the code is not releasing the Groovy Classloader? Something is keeping a reference to it, and I need to analyze the running system to find it (through a memory dump or similar). I already found the classes polluting the permanent space by using jmap, but I need to dig deeper than that. I am unfortunately not able to disclose our 20MB of source code through stackoverflow :-)