# Classes Loaded by GroovyClassLoader not listed

Tags: java, groovy, classloader

I am investigating memory leak in some JVM bsaed code (groovy running in a Java env).

I have a simple Java test class that I am using to investigate various behaviours around Groovy class loading, and I am running the following code (from plain Java):

```
GroovyClassLoader localGroovyClassLoader = new GroovyClassLoader();
Class clazz = localGroovyClassLoader.loadClass("com.test.Example", true, false, true);
```

Where `Example` is just a simple Groovy class (doesn't do anything particular as its just my dummy case).

Now, if immediately after the above code I log the following:

```
localGroovyClassLoader.getLoadedClasses().length
```

It logs a 0 - despite that I can verify that my loaded class is all good (`clazz` outputs that it is in fact `Example`).

The reason I want to use the `getLoadedClasses()` method is because I am dynamically reloading groovy on the fly, so when reloading I want to also clear the meta registry (as detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10484023/258813 ) - so was planning on using the following code:

```
for (Class c : localGroovyClassLoader.getLoadedClasses()){
    GroovySystem.getMetaClassRegistry().removeMetaClass(c);
}
```

But obviously, if `getLoadedClasses()` returns 0 despite having just loaded a class I will not be able to run the above code.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the `com.test.Example` compiled class in the parent classloader?  If so the GCL won't have to load the class itself, it'll just delegate to its parent loader.

Comment: @IanRoberts is right. See https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.java#L648

Comment: @IanRoberts Yep, you are right.. a link to the compiled groovy class was on my classpath so getting loaded up at launch. If you want to add that as a formal answer I can mark it correct?

Comment: @rhinds I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the `com.test.Example` compiled class in the parent classloader? Calling `getLoadedClasses` only gives you the classes that this GCL loaded directly itself. If it was able to find a particular class by delegating to its parent loader then it doesn't need to load the class itself, and the class won't be included in `getLoadedClasses`.