# Groovy GroovyClassLoader JVM Caching and Updating Loaded Classes

Tags: java, groovy, jvm, classloader

I'm testing the dynamic loading of JARS with a `GroovyClassLoader`. We will be updating the JARs frequently, so we need to re-load the JAR (more specifically, the class) when changes are made without restarting the JVM.  Is this possible?

I do `classLoader.addUrl(path)` once, and the JAR is loaded into memory. I can then generate instances in subsequent scripts without needing to load the class again (that seems like caching which is fine).

The problem is that I tried doing `classLoader.clearCache()`, and it doesn't seem to have had any effect. `.classCache` and `.sourceCache` are empty. But, I can still generate instances. I tried getting the **parent classloader**, but it doesn't show any trace of the loaded *package/class*. I'm not sure where it is living.

I also read this article, and no I do not have the class compiled in the JVM.

[Classes Loaded by GroovyClassLoader not listed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461773/classes-loaded-by-groovyclassloader-not-listed)

I don't think my code is relevant, but here it is anyway.

```
GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader()
def jarFile = new File("C:/sandbox-test-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar")
classLoader.addURL(jarFile.toURI().toURL())
def mySand = Class.forName("com.test.Sandbox").newInstance()
println mySand.dump()
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, my understanding is that you are trying to replace an existing jar with a newer version of the jar in your classpath. If that is the case, wouldn't calling classLoader.addUrl(path) with the new jar path simply add the new version of the jar to the end of the classpath? I believe the result of that would be that you now have 2 versions of your jar in the classpath and more importantly, Java will find the old version listed first in the classpath and never load classes from the new jar unless they are new classes that didn't exist in the original one.

Comment: That is indeed the case, and indeed the problem.  With the help of an amazing Groovy guru, I am now working toward the following solution:  1.  Write a new class which serves to create and manipulate a new UrlClassLoader() at start time which then loads all my JAR URLS. That classloader will be stored in the JVM as a static variable, allowing all my custom code to find that classloader.  Most importantly, my "Updater" process will run every 10 minutes, and if it detects changes to any jars, it will set that variable to null, and then re-make it, pulling fresh copies of the JARS in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Sascha showed me a brilliantly simple workaround.

To "Update" a classloader, one can simply nullify the existing one and remake:

```
classloader = null
classloader = new GroovyClassLoader()
classLoader.addURL(jarFile.toURI().toURL())
```

The classloader is only needed when classes are being requested.

This is simple in my use case. Perhaps others will have more complicated scenarios that might make this not work.