# Groovy script gets cached after being executed by Sling

Tags: groovy, aem, sling

I was looking at the Sling documentation and noticed that [Groovy scripts can be used to render a component](https://sling.apache.org/old-stuff/scriptengineintegration/groovy-support.html), similar to the way JSP or HTL can be used.

Now, I'm not very fond of the idea and I think that the place of Groovy code should be in OSGi bundles but I decided to try and see what I can do with these scripts.

I created a simple component with a dialog that has a single property, *text*. Let's call this component `simpleGroovy`. Here's the rough structure (dialog details omitted for brevity).

```
/apps/example/core/components/simpleGroovy
|
|- cq:editConfig
|- dialog
|- simpleGroovy.groovy
```

The contents of `simpleGroovy.groovy` are something like this:

```
println "Hello Groovy! Rendering the contents of ${resource.path} since 2017"
```

As expected, the script executed just fine, GStrings and all.

However, when I change the script after making the first request, I keep getting the same output. If I rename the script and use a selector, I get an output matching the current state of the script. Until the first request when this also gets cached.

I'm curious as to the cause of this. I suppose the Groovy script gets compiled to a Java class at some point and that the class gets cached somewhere.

I'm on AEM 6.2 so I checked the contents `/crx-quickstart/launchpad/felix/bundle305/data/classes` (bundle `305` is the id of the `org.apache.sling.commons.fsclassloader` in my environment).

I can see the compiled classes for JSP and HTL scripts from my `example` app but there seems to be nothing related to my Groovy script in any of those folders.

I also looked up the ID of my Groovy Runtime (`groovy-all`) bundle but there's no data folder in there. However, restarting the *Groovy Runtime* bundle allows me to see the changes I made to my script.

Is there an easier way I could cause the Groovy script to be recompiled? What exactly gets cached and where does it sit?

Comment: can you let me know what are the steps you did for integrating groovy to aem, I have created a component and added a `.groovy` instead of. `Jsp` in the components script file and added **groovy-all** bundle into felix console, and when I tried to render this component, I don't see any output in the page for this component.

Comment: @krish I didn't perform any extra steps but that's probably because I had installed a bunch of Groovy-related packages prior to learning about the option to use a Groovy script in this manne. I'm using the [AEM Groovy Console](https://github.com/OlsonDigital/cq-groovy-console) pretty much all the time. I suppose whatever bundles I needed were already deployed as part of that package.

Comment: thank you, am not sure whether this will help out generally to recompile all JSPs we can use the [slingjsp](http://localhost:4502/system/console/slingjsp) , but for the groovy scripts we are going to have a external Servlet engine as bundle i guess we have only option of restarting the groovy bundle to clear the cache.

Answer (score 1):

sling uses Groovy provided [GroovyScriptEngine](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/2990a73f4dcf230c40a80d2c1e555ffa39d6262f/contrib/scripting/groovy/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/scripting/groovy/scripting/internal/GSPScriptEngine.java#L43), which stores compiled scripts in memory, see [scriptCache](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/a52d0d3c5dd1cbb342992d36235171718a563c8b/src/main/groovy/util/GroovyScriptEngine.java#L98).

I dont think there is anything available ootb to clear scriptCache. you will have to write your own groovy scriptengine and probably classloader. (not 100% sure about this though)

Comment: Is there a way to clear the cache without restarting the bundle? Maybe be a button in the Felix console or a service exposed by the OSGi bundle.

Comment: No.I dont think there is anything available ootb to clear scriptCache.

Comment: am not sure how to reproduce this issue, but have a look at this [JVM Groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192157/groovy-groovyclassloader-jvm-caching-and-updating-loaded-classes)