# GroovyClassLoader and permgen

Tags: java, groovy

We unfortunately got PermgenError. jmap -permstat return something like this:

```
0x00000006c17f8520  1   1968    0x00000006ad000000  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x00000007e00686e0
0x00000006babab308  3   19920   0x00000006b6874f88  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x00000007e975bb80
0x00000006bca26800  3   15776   0x00000006b6874f88  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x00000007e975bb80
0x00000006bb84db80  3   16176   0x00000006b6874f88  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x00000007e975bb80
0x00000006b71dffd0  3   19272   0x00000006b6874f88  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x00000007e975bb80
```

after 2 hours jmap -permstat return:

```
0x00000006c17f8520  1   1968    0x00000006ad000000  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x00000007e00686e0
0x00000006babab308  3   19920   0x00000006b6874f88  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x00000007e975bb80
0x00000006bca26800  43  437232 0x00000006b6874f88   dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x00000007e975bb80
0x00000006bb84db80  3   16176   0x00000006b6874f88  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x00000007e975bb80
0x00000006b71dffd0  7   16176 0x00000006b6874f88    dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x00000007e975bb80
```

As you can see the number of class loaded by classLoader incresed for example from 3 to 43.
This is only short fragment of permstat - (total = 4676 53521   436264528 alive=1, dead=4675). We run java with parameters:

```
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=800 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:CMSFullGCsBeforeCompaction=1 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

but in permstat all clasloaders are dead.
Our code which parse groovy classes:

```
class GroovyInvoker {

    private static GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader(Thread.currentThread()
            .getContextClassLoader());

    protected static GroovyInvoker getInstance(String fileName, String className)
            throws BaseScriptingException {

        GroovyInvoker instance = new GroovyInvoker();
        instance.setFileName(fileName);
        instance.setClassName(className);
        Class clazz;
        clazz = GroovyInvoker.gcl.parseClass(instance.getFile(fileName));
        Script aScript = (Script) clazz.newInstance();
        instance.setScript(aScript);

        return instance;
    }           
}
```

I read this topic: [Locating code that is filling PermGen with dead Groovy code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815952/locating-code-that-is-filling-permgen-with-dead-groovy-code) and answer with metaClassRegistry problem but we can't test it now on prod server. My questions is:
why number of classes loaded by GroovyClassLoader is increasing when Groovy is using cache? Shouldn't this number be constant? 
why gc is not collecting dead classLoaders?

Java version 1.6.0_26.
Groovy version 1.5.8.

Comment: Which version of Groovy?

Comment: Version of groovy: 1.5.6

Answer (score 1):

I think its related to this:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-6494

If you don't need the context classloader, then GroovyClassLoader won't leak.