# Adding a library to java web app causes java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space?

Tags: tomcat, permgen

When I try to add a library (in this case: iText-2.0.8.jar) to my java web app (JSF) and restart Tomcat, everything seems fine. The login page also renders. When I login however, the application almost immediately throws the infamous `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` error.

Increasing the PermGen size with `-XX:MaxPermGen=128M` doesn't solve the issue, not even with large amounts such as 2048m.
When I remove the added jar, everything's fine again.

Does anyone have an idea how to diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sifting through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error), I read [this blog post](http://www.jroller.com/agileanswers/entry/preventing_java_s_java_lang).

I just switched to the JRockit JVM, and so far I haven't encountered any `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` errors.

As a bonus, my web application now also runs faster.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had almost exactly the same issue running XWiki on Jetty using java 6 on Windows 2000 server 64 bit.

Adding the following 2 command line switches solved it for me:

- -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
- -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled

Sorry the above didn't help.
Try this `-XX:MaxPermSize=128M` instead of `-XX:MaxPermGen=128M`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it didn't resolve my problem.

Comment: Still no luck, I'm going to get some sleep and fumble some more with these options tomorrow.