# Why When I run tomcat inside eclipse, get Exceptions in deployed projects but when start from startup.bat or IntelliJ, everyThing is OK?

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, deployment, config

I have a mavenized multi module project that has parent pom with "pom" packaging, and some modules with "jar" and a module with "war" packaging.
That war module has dynamicWebModule 3.0 facet.
I added tomcat 8.5 in eclipse 2020-06 for java ee developers and set in server overview tab that eclipse should use the original tomcat and should deploy my projects to catalina.home/webapps.
When I deploy my project inside eclipse, My project can not read a properties file and throws FileNotFoundException,
but if I close eclipse and start tomcat with startup.bat file, everything is ok and I can see my homePage in browser.
EveryThing is same, even I did not undeploy my project that deployed inside eclipse, and I could not figure out what is wrong with eclipse's configs.
This project uses spring 4.7 and runs on jdk 1.8.
I even tested with IntelliJ IDEA and had no problem.
These are arguments that set in eclipse's run configuration. program arguments: start.
vm arguments: -Dcatalina.base="D:\Tomcat8" -Dcatalina.home="D:\Tomcat8" -Dwtp.deploy="D:\Tomcat8\webapps" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="D:\Tomcat8\endorsed"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When eclipse runs tomcat, it does not run OS dependent files like startup.bat or setEnv.bat.
In case of this project, it had some environment variables in catalina.home/bin/setEnv.bat.
I get to [run configuration](https://www.subjectcoach.com/tutorials/detail/contents/beginners-guide-to-eclipse-ide/chapter/working-with-run-configurations) of war module, and from environment tab, added those variables that is in setEnv.bat.
see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870225/how-to-set-jvm-arguments-in-tomcat-that-work-both-in-eclipse-and-using-the-start) for more information about how eclipse runs tomcat.