# Debugging gives PermGen space error in Netbeans

Tags: debugging, netbeans

I have Netbeans 7.0 and Spring application. I try to debug application, I always get PermGen space error. It runs normally. I'm new with debugging so can anyone give any hints how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Not sure what pemgem is, program? Pretty sure its not [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mims.com%2FIndia%2Fdrug%2Finfo%2FPEMGEM%2FPEMGEM%2520vial&ei=2evNTvCFM-ji2AXvguWPDw&usg=AFQjCNF7vs6rZdNkZpWTLz100UoFydUC6Q&sig2=q_XIadjjl9abcLsDYxOX3Q) :-)

Comment: Sorry, my dyslexic typo. It's permgem!!

Comment: Did any of the links in my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this Fresh Blurbs entry: [Explaining java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space](http://www.freshblurbs.com/explaining-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space). [Understanding and avoiding the Java Permgen Space error](http://www.integratingstuff.com/2011/07/24/understanding-and-avoiding-the-java-permgen-space-error/) also discusses this memory leak problem. Last but not least take a look at this: [Dealing with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/88235/1007364).

Answer (score 0):

when i faced this problem it was after the number of look ups loaded on start up increased to some high number but my team didnt have this problem so 
i tried a lot on the internet but the solution for me was

**whenever i want to debug**
i login to a new windows account i created and debug smoothly

i don't know why it worked
but i think net-beans on a new account has its default Gui IDE configuration as its just installed and it worked fine for me because i dont need to debug alot but the problem is there

it worked once so i installed another windows on another drive it worked for sure fast

hope it helps

****oops i edit what i posted it crashed again pergem space !! :(