# Problems with deploying application on Tomcat Server

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, jsf-2, tomcat7

For some time I'm learning JSF/Java EE. From the beginning I've an annoying problem with deploying my application using Netbeans to Tomcat7 server.

The app is deploying on every save but sometimes deploy suspends and I need to stop debugging, kill the java process and start debug again. It is really annoying but I don't know how to solve this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not a good question and it's not even directly related to JSF. Tomcat has notoriously screwy classloading process and it's even more pronounced IMO within NB. Rephrase your question, either with steps to reproduce or a stacktrace before the community reacts to the question.

Comment: That's most plausibly is caused by `OutOfMemoryError` which is in its turn caused by shortage of PermGen memory space. See [Dealing with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error) question and its answers for some details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PermGen Space error on hot deploys on Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744219/permgen-space-error-on-hot-deploys-on-tomcat)