# Java Linux 64 bit PermGen options?

Tags: java, linux, 64-bit

Running a rake build using jruby using:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

While I already have `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`, I'm still getting `PermGen space` failure.

Are there some other command line options to use to increase the PermGen space available?

Thanks

Comment: reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085028/what-to-do-with-tomcat-permgen-space higher value like `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m` is also valid

Comment: This is somewhat akin to asking, "I was walking, and then I stopped. Why did I stop?" You've given nowhere near enough context for anyone to provide any helpful advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a memory profiler or heap analysis tool to inspect exactly what is going into your PermGen.  It is unusual to require a huge amount of PermGen and unless you know exactly what and why you're doing it, it's probably a bug.

You need to post your code, describe the application better, or do some basic heap analysis yourself.  Not nearly enough information to help much as-is.