# Tomcat Heap settings in catalina.sh not working

Tags: linux, tomcat, catalina

In linux Tomcat bin folder, I want to set `JAVA_OPTS` for heap memory, I have done settings like `export CATALINA_OPTS="-server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"` and then restarting but still my heap memory is not updating.

Can you guide me? Where to put these attributes in *catalina.sh* or am I missing something or do I have to modify somewhere else?

Comment: I think this stack overflow link may help you out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392255/permgen-space-error-in-tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You should set custom Java options in `setenv.sh`, not `catalina.sh`.

> Do not set the variables in this script. Instead put them into a script
>   setenv.sh in CATALINA_BASE/bin to keep your customizations separate.
>   (c) catalina.sh

I just fixed the same issue... Earlier I used to modify `catalina.sh` for that purpose and it worked somehow, but not with my current Tomcat 7.0.52.0.