# OutOfMemory error Permgen space due to dynamic proxy objects

Tags: spring, out-of-memory, permgen, proxies

I am repeatedly deploying and undeploying the same Spring based application on my server.
This is an Oracle Event Processing application and the container uses Spring heavily.

From jprofiler I see multiple instances of org.springframework.osgi.context.internal.classloader.ChainedClassL
oader loading classes like com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6179.

It seems these classes are never unloaded with successive deployments.
From the object reference graph I see that classes like StaticServiceProxyCreator
OsgiServiceCollectionProxyFactory hold references to these proxy objects.

How can I get rid of this error on JDK 7?
Increasing Permgen space is not the solution, as it only delays the error.

Thanks,
Yogesh

Comment: AFAIK, this is a known problem of Tomcat in an Oracle JVM, with no workaround (unless using another container or another JVM). References : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392255/permgen-space-error-in-tomcat