# Jacoco code coverage java agent error

Tags: tomcat, code-coverage, jacoco, integration-testing

I am using jacoco agent to generate code coverage report for my simple rest api

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value ="/test/{id}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getResponse(@PathVariable("id")int value){

        if(value>10){
            System.out.println("Value is greater than 10");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Value is no longer greater than 10");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ServiceResponse("Service executed"));
    }
}
```

Now i am providing JVM arguments to tomcat in setenv.bat file like

```
SET JAVA_OPTS="%JAVA_OPTS% -javaagent:E:/Office/CodeCoverage/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=E:/Office/CodeCoverage/jacoco.exec,append=false"
```

but when i install tomcat as a service it gives this error although service is installed successfully

```
Filename ,directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

kindly guide me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set JAVA\_OPTS for Tomcat in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731174/how-to-set-java-opts-for-tomcat-in-windows)

Comment: @Godin I have tried all the thing mentioned in the above link but still no success

Comment: Then something is missing in your explanation - I just downloaded Tomcat 9.0.10, created setenv.bat to use JaCoCo agent and it perfectly starts on Windows. So where / when this message appears?  Where is complete stacktrace? Are there other messages around? etc