# Configure G1G1 AggressiveHeap

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I have problem with starting tomcat (catalina.sh) when I decide to use G1GC with AggressiveHeap parameter like this:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=myservice -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx30G -XX:+AggressiveHeap"
```

but when I try to start tomcat, I receive this error:

> Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED

My JDK version is 1.8
My OS is Oracle linux 6.9
My tomcat version is 8.5.31

how can I fix that?

Comment: What is your problem? The JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS are used in addition to your JAVA_OPTIONS (and seem to target Java 9+), but that is not an error. Does Tomcat refuse to start? If so what do you find in the logs?

Comment: Not answering your question/solving your problem, but please [use CATALINA_OPTS, not JAVA_OPTS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24734330/)