# error message "/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: 1: eval: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Tags: tomcat, sh, catalina, catalina.out

In my catalina.out I have this error

> /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: 1: eval: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

I think this means that a string is declared with a quotation mark (") but it doesn't have the closing quotation mark, but I don't find the error.

Any suggestions to find the error?

I use tomcat 8.5.3.32 and I only add this to catalina.sh

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

Comment: ...and...? If you expect us to tell you where the missing quotation mark belongs, you left out some  information that might be particularly useful for us to locate the problem... (please see [ask])

Comment: I added one detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to restore the default `catalina.sh` file and *never* change it.

Instead, create a `setenv.sh` file in the same directory, and do all of your configuration there. That file will not be overwritten by a future tomcat upgrade, and will continue to keep your personal configuration changes going forward.

For the problem at hand: Evaluate if your $JAVA_OPTS already contains quotes - e.g. through a directory that contains a space. And make sure the whole expanded line is properly formatted.

But an even better fix: You don't want to make the changes you're doing in JAVA_OPTS, but in CATALINA_OPTS ([here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24734330/13447)). Set its value - in `setenv.sh` - to

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

(or follow the other recommendation from my linked answer and use identical memory settings for -Xms and -Xmx)