# Deployment time of ~150MB war file from jenkins to tomcat 9

Tags: performance, jenkins, tomcat, deployment

Our jenkins checks every 5 minutes if the SCM has changed and if yes, it starts a build with sonarqube, jacoco and finally a deployment on a tomcat over the internal network.

This works most of the times very good, sometimes I have to remove the old versions and restart tomcat.

What drives me almost mad is that it takes sooooooo long. I already observed that the ~140MB are completely uploaded but jenkins still waits for something. I adapted the values in the manager web.xml multipart config to 200MB each.

Any help or idea or question is very appreciated!
Thanks a lot!
Aurel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using webhook (from Github, gitlab) instead of check git repo every 5 minutes. It will help you get changes from Git repo faster.

[image]

War file have been deploy many times, maybe you need to `un-deloy` app before copy new version of war file to `re-deploy`.

Tomcat does need a lot of permgen. Try to modify it. [[Refer]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085028/what-to-do-with-tomcat-permgen-space)