# configuring tomcat such as finding bin directory

Tags: debian, tomcat6

I am trying to configure tomcat according to [Dealing with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error). How do I implement the steps

- You can do that by shutting down the tomcat service, then going into the Tomcat/bin directory and running tomcat6w.exe. Under the "Java" tab, add the arguments to the "Java Options" box. Click "OK" and then restart the service.

So I do the first part shutdown tomcat:

- sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 stop

How do I implement the rest? I am running debian linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions you quote relate to a Windows machine.

It would appear you installed Tomcat from a Debian package.If so, your bin subdirectory should be be under */usr/share/tomcat...*

There you can change your permgen settings in ***../bin/setenv.sh***(file might need to be created) with *-XX:MaxPermSize.*

For example:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-XX:PermSize=256m"
```

Comment: I found the /usr/share/tomcat6/bin directory. But where is setenv.sh? Thanks. +1 for your help.

Comment: I try to upvote, the system says I need 15 reputation first. Thanks all the same.

Comment: setenv.sh does not exist a priori in the distribution. You can create it in the bin subdir.