# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:PermGen space

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dealing with “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error)

In Catalina.out log, I am getting the below mentioned exception. Application is too slow.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:PermGen space

What I need to do?

Comment: what type of application, please describe properly

Comment: The applications deployed in tomcat are too slow

Comment: You are using more memory than you have. It is possible you have a memory leak.

Comment: Application too slow `->` profile application and improve performance

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the heap size.

Maybe this:

`export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m"`

and then use VisualVM to track memory usage:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/intro.html