# Starting up Grails application on Tomcat7

Tags: grails, tomcat7, searchable, grails-searchable, searchable-plugin

I am struggling with an issue trying to start up a Grails 2.0.4 application in a new environment with Tomcat7. I am trying to log everything but I am not being able to find the source of the problem.

The output in catalina.out is

```
SEVERE: Context [/comenego] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Looking the specific log for the application, I don´t see any error at all. The last lines are these:

```
2014-01-26 12:57:18,687 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  config.CompassConfiguration  - Mapping InputStream [package/corpus/Field.cpm.xml]
2014-01-26 12:57:18,698 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  config.CompassConfiguration  - Mapping InputStream [package/corpus/Company.cpm.xml]
2014-01-26 12:57:18,713 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  config.CompassConfiguration  - Mapping InputStream [package/corpus/User.cpm.xml]
2014-01-26 12:57:18,725 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  config.CompassConfiguration  - Mapping InputStream [package/corpus/Author.cpm.xml]
2014-01-26 12:57:18,736 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  config.CompassConfiguration  - Mapping InputStream [package/corpus/TextType.cpm.xml]
2014-01-26 12:57:18,758 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  config.CompassConfiguration  - Mapping InputStream [package/corpus/Text.cpm.xml]
2014-01-26 12:57:18,766 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  config.CompassConfiguration  - Mapping InputStream [package/corpus/SourceType.cpm.xml]
2014-01-26 12:57:18,773 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  config.CompassConfiguration  - Mapping InputStream [package/corpus/Copyright.cpm.xml]
2014-01-26 12:57:18,782 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  config.CompassConfiguration  - Mapping InputStream [package/corpus/Language.cpm.xml]
2014-01-26 12:57:18,798 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  config.CompassConfiguration  - Mapping InputStream [package/corpus/Paragraph.cpm.xml]
2014-01-26 12:57:18,811 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  config.CompassConfiguration  - Mapping InputStream [package/corpus/Discourse.cpm.xml]
2014-01-26 12:57:38,058 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  util.SessionIdGenerator  - Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [19,039] milliseconds.
```

I am almost 100% sure that the problem comes because I am using the Searchable plugin version 0.6.3 and the database is getting really big at the moment, but I locally I am using the same database as in production and it starts up without any problem, and my laptop doesn´t have more resources that the server.

These are the tools I am using:

Grails 2.0.4
JDK 1.7.0_51
Ubuntu 12.04
Tomcat 7

Any idea what can I do to find the source of the problems?

Comment: When you say locally you mean in GGTS or in a local Tomcat?

Comment: Actually I am using IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: I never used IntelliJ, but in GGTS when you run your app from there it run in development environment. I think that is the problem (the different configurations) or it has to do with tomcat configurations (eg try to increase your Tomcat's memory http://stackoverflow.com/a/12688838/1806218)