# tomcat stopping error on server using putty

Tags: java, centos, tomcat7, putty, vps

i am getting error in stopping tomcat service in server using putty

error is

```
`[root@vps ~]# service tomcat7 stop
 Shutting down Tomcat7:
 Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/tomcat7
 Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/tomcat7
 Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/tomcat7/temp
 Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
 Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar
/usr/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
 Error occurred during initialization of VM
 Could not reserve enough space for object heap
 Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
 Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

`
please help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing the heap memory usage for java.
You can do so by editing catalina.bat (for Windows) and catalina.sh (for Linux).

Try editing JAVA_OPTS.

For Linux
export JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xmx512m"

For Windows
set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xmx512m

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your memory settings for tomcat, to help set heap size look at

[Increase Tomcat memory settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688778/increase-tomcat-memory-settings)

Take a look at the question about memory size

[Could not reserve enough space for object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401396/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)