# What to set for JVM heap memory for tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, out-of-memory, jpedal

I am using Jpedal tool to convert PDF to Image. In general this is working, however once in a while during converting large number of PDF pages into images it causes the application and tomcat to stop without any information or logs. Seems it's Out of Memory Error without any logs.
I have increased JVM heap memory for tomcat as below :

```
-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
```

But still it causes tomcat to stop.
Can anyone please help for the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688778/increase-tomcat-memory-settings/12688838#12688838 take a look here

Comment: You could also try and find out a bit more information by obtaining a Dump when the VM exits:  JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/path/to/dir'

Comment: I have increased JVM heap memory for tomcat as below :- 

JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:CompileCommandFile=.hotspot_compiler"

but still getting sane error