# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Perm Gen Space..again

Tags: spring, jsp, out-of-memory, weblogic11g, permgen

I followed the instructions from several great posts in dealing with this error when compiling my JSP and it seemed to go away ---for a while, but now it's back with a vengeance :( 
First off here are the 'specs':

- Spring 3.1.0 release
- Using WebLogic Server 10.3.5,
- Adjusted the STS.ini file to read as follows:

  ```
  -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
  -Xmn28m
  -Xms120m
  -Xmx2048m
  -Xss1m
  -XX:PermSize=256m
  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
  ```

and here is the error I am receiving when trying to view my page:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:630)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:614)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.jdt.internal.compiler.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:256)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.jdt.internal.compiler.ClassFilePool.acquire(ClassFilePool.java:34)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.jdt.internal.compiler.ClassFile.getNewInstance(ClassFile.java:229)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:512)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:611)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.generateCode(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:358)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:770)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:464)
at weblogic.jsp.internal.java.JDTJavaCompiler.generateByteCode(JDTJavaCompiler.java:104)
at weblogic.jsp.internal.java.JavaSourceFile._codeGen(JavaSourceFile.java:211)
at weblogic.jsp.internal.java.JavaSourceFile.codeGen(JavaSourceFile.java:201)
at weblogic.jsp.internal.ProxySourceFile.compileGeneratedFiles(ProxySourceFile.java:310)
at weblogic.jsp.internal.ProxySourceFile.codeGen(ProxySourceFile.java:248)
at weblogic.jsp.internal.SourceFile.codeGen(SourceFile.java:327)
at weblogic.jsp.internal.client.ClientUtilsImpl$CodeGenJob.run(ClientUtilsImpl.java:599)
at weblogic.jsp.internal.client.Job.performJob(Job.java:83)
at weblogic.jsp.internal.client.ThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPool.java:217)
```

The error went away a week ago after adjusting the default PermSize (don't remember what it was set to)...is there anything else I should be looking for here?

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error)

Comment: Thanks @dadu ..I was actually looking at that answer earlier this morning but can't find the Tomcat file mentioned. The server I am running is one set up by my job using WebLogicServer so not really sure if Tomcat is involoved...?

Answer (score 1):

As a follow on to George D's answer: For weblogic, any changes to JVM args should be put in $DOMAIN_HOME/bin/setDomainEnv.sh (this is for Linux, should be a similar path for Windows).