# tomcat7 fails to run with JPA

Tags: jsf, jpa, tomcat7

I am working on a  Java EE application  with JSF(using JSF Majorra 2.1.6) et JPA(using the librairies EclipseLink Juno) and tomcat 7 server . 
The problem is when i add a JPA application to the tomcat, Tomcat fails to run and i have the following msg at the end of the console :

```
                       Infos: Cleaned up javabean caches
                       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
                                              at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
                                              at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
                                              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                                              at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferencesRmiTargets(WebappClassLoader.java:2556)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferences(WebappClassLoader.java:1961)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.stop(WebappClassLoader.java:1864)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.stopInternal(WebappLoader.java:658)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:225)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5509)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:225)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1055)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:978)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:379)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:324)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
                                              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This should answer you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error

Comment: Also, could you reformat your code please?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running out of memory.

You need to increase the size of your heap or perm size.