# jstack in mixed mode: WrongTypeException: No suitable match for type of address

Tags: java, multithreading, ubuntu, jstack

I'm trying to run jstack on ubuntu in mixed mode:

```
 $ jstack -m 7219
```

The result is this exception:

```
Attaching to process ID 7219, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
  JVM version is 25.162-b12
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)        
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:140)
    at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:106)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to deduce type of thread from address 0x00007f02cc002800 (expected type JavaThread, CompilerThread, ServiceThread, JvmtiAgentThread, or SurrogateLockerThread)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads.createJavaThreadWrapper(Threads.java:166)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads.first(Threads.java:150)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.PStack.initJFrameCache(PStack.java:200)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.PStack.run(PStack.java:71)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.PStack.run(PStack.java:58)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.PStack.run(PStack.java:53)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.run(JStack.java:66)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.startInternal(Tool.java:260)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:223)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:92)
    ... 6 more
  Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.types.WrongTypeException: No suitable match for type of address 0x00007f02cc002800
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.InstanceConstructor.newWrongTypeException(InstanceConstructor.java:62)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VirtualConstructor.instantiateWrapperFor(VirtualConstructor.java:80)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads.createJavaThreadWrapper(Threads.java:162)
    ... 16 more
```

The process with PID 7219 was started with the same user as jstack.

Comment: This can be either a bug in HotSpot Serviceability Agent or an attempt to get a stacktrace while JVM is in inconsistent state. In both cases you can hardly do anything about it.

Comment: Why do you want `-m` mode? If you are interested in non-Java stack, then `gdb` should be a better tool for this.

Comment: I'm observing long running requests in a web application. Threaddumps point at native classloading methods.  My question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49507981/unsafe-defineclass-hangs-slow-reflection-calls lead to this tooling issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue on Ubuntu, with `openjdk-9-jdk-headless` installed, `jstack` alone would work fine but `jstack -m` would fail with same error as you.

Installing `openjdk-9-dbg` (package that brings debug symbols) solved it.

Comment: Exactly the same issue: jstack without the mixed mode flag is running fine. But i'm using Oracle jdk 1.8.0_172.

Answer (score 0):

The same user is fine, but make also sure you are using the jstack that is bundled the **exact same** JVM as the one that is running the process 7219.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I'm using the jstack of the jvm which runs the process.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using HSDB on openjdk-8. Installing lib `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-dbg` works.