# Tomcat Memory Exception

Tags: java, tomcat

I am a complete Tomcat novice but I need to use it to run a bit of Rest API software. Everything is great apart from the response I am getting when we try to run a request. Any tips - for a novice -  on how to fix this would be really appreciated!

Thanks

```
"response":"<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.40 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space</h1><HR size=\"1\" noshade=\"noshade\"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space\n\torg.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:972)\n\torg.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)\n\torg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)\n\torg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)\n\tjavax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)\n\tjavax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)\n\torg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)\n\torg.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)\n\torg.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)\n</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space\n</pre></p><p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.40 logs.</u></p><HR size=\"1\" noshade=\"noshade\"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.40</h3></body></html>"
    }
```

Comment: You couldn't clean that up in a text editor, or view it in a browser, so it's readable?  Don't post here, what can't be (or you haven't tried) to read.

Answer (score 0):

You have a

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen
```

as can seen in the error report. Have a look at this question [Dealing with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error)

Comment: Thanks for this - I actually upgraded the EC2 server to a bigger variety and it seemed to fix the issue